# Evaluate expression given as a string

Tags: r, eval, r-faq

I'm curious to know if R can use its `eval()` function to perform calculations provided by e.g. a string.

This is a common case:

```
eval("5+5")
```

However, instead of 10 I get:

```
[1] "5+5"
```

Any solution?

Comment: Despite all the answers showing how to solve that with parse ... Why do you need to store language types in a character `string` ? Martin Mächler's answer should deserve much more upvotes.

Comment: Thank you @PetrMatousu.   Yes, I'm shocked to see how mis-information is spread on SO now..  by people upvoting  `eval(parse(text = *))`  fake solutions.

Comment: I want to run scrips of the form: `QQ = c('11','12','13','21','22','23')`, i.e.: QQ =c(...,'ij',..) with i,j varying on a range that is may vary from run to run. For this and similar examples, I can write the script as `paste( "QQ = c('", paste(rep(1:2,each=3),1:3, sep="", collapse="','"), "')",sep="")`, and the option `eval(parse(text=...))` creates the vector QQ in the working environment as per the script. What would be the proper R coder way to do this, if not with "text=..."?

Comment: @MartinMächler how is `eval(parse(text = "5+5"))` a "fake solution"? It seems to work fine for all the cases I have tried. There are reasons that one might need to evaluate something read-in as a string. I am finding your answer more confusing and less useful to evaluating a string (OP) than the others, which might be why the other answers have more upvotes?

Comment: @VictorZurkowski: With your example, written in a "generalizable way",                       `i <- rep(1:2, each=3) ;   j <- 1:3`         the proper solution is (many times faster and more readable)     `QQ <-  paste0(i, j)`  -- voilà, that's all.

Answer (score 521, accepted):

The `eval()` function evaluates an expression, but `"5+5"` is a string, not an expression. Use `parse()` with `text=<string>` to change the string into an expression:

```
> eval(parse(text="5+5"))
[1] 10
> class("5+5")
[1] "character"
> class(parse(text="5+5"))
[1] "expression"
```

Calling `eval()` invokes many behaviours, some are not immediately obvious:

```
> class(eval(parse(text="5+5")))
[1] "numeric"
> class(eval(parse(text="gray")))
[1] "function"
> class(eval(parse(text="blue")))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'blue' not found
```

See also [tryCatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12193902/59087).

Comment: As Shane notes below, "You need to specify that the input is text, because parse expects a file by default"

Comment: the side-effects of using eval(parse) should be specified. For example, if you have a pre-defined variable **name** equal to "David" and you reassign using eval(parse(text = "name") == "Alexander", you will get an error because eval & parse do not return an R expression that can be evaluated.

Comment: @NelsonGon: Unevaluated expressions constructed using `quote()`, `bquote()`, or the more sophisticated tools provided by the `rlang` package.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov Thanks, I somehow keep coming back to this question looking for  an alternative. I've looked at `rlang` but the closest I found was `parse_expr` which calls `parse_exprs` which in turn is the same as using `parse` and wrapping it in `eval` which seems to be the same thing as done here. I am unsure what the advantage would be of using `rlang`.

Comment: @NelsonGon: with `rlang`, you would work directly with expressions, not strings. No parse step necessary. It has two advantages. 1. Expression manipulations will always produce valid expressions. String manipulations will only produce valid strings. You won't know if they are valid expressions until you parse them. 2. There's no equivalent to the `substitute()` class of functions in the string world, which severely limits your ability to manipulate function calls. Consider [this glm wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57528229/300187). What would a string equivalent look like?

Answer (score 120):

You can use the `parse()` function to convert the characters into an expression.  You need to specify that the input is text, because parse expects a file by default:

```
eval(parse(text="5+5"))
```

Comment: > fortunes::fortune("answer is parse")

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)

>

Comment: @MartinMächler That's ironic, because the core R packages use `parse` all the time! https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=extension%3AR+parse&type=

Answer (score 67):

Sorry but I don't understand why too many people even think a string was something that could be evaluated. You must change your mindset, really.
Forget all connections between strings on one side and expressions, calls, evaluation on the other side.

The (possibly) only connection is via `parse(text = ....)` and all good R programmers should know that this is rarely an efficient or safe means to construct expressions (or calls). Rather learn more about `substitute()`, `quote()`, and possibly the power of using `do.call(substitute, ......)`.

```
fortunes::fortune("answer is parse")
# If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
#    -- Thomas Lumley
#       R-help (February 2005)
```

Dec.2017: Ok, here is an example (in comments, there's no nice formatting):

```
q5 <- quote(5+5)
str(q5)
# language 5 + 5

e5 <- expression(5+5)
str(e5)
# expression(5 + 5)
```

and if you get more experienced you'll learn that `q5` is a `"call"` whereas `e5` is an `"expression"`, and even that `e5[[1]]` is identical to `q5`:

```
identical(q5, e5[[1]])
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: could you give an example? maybe you could show us how to "hold on" to 5+5 in an r object, then evaluate it later, using quote and substitute rather than a character and eval(parse(text=)?

Comment: I may be a little lost. At what point do you get 10? Or is that not the point?

Comment: @RichardDiSalvo: yes, `q5 <- quote(5+5)` above *is* the expression (actually the "call") `5+5` and it is an R object, but not a string.   You can evaluate it any time.      Again:  using,  quote(), substitute(), ... **instead** parse creates calls or expressions directly and more efficiently than via parse(text= . ).        Using  `eval()` is fine,  using `parse(text=*)` is error prone and sometimes quite inefficient in comparison to construction calls and manipulating them..   @Nick S:   It's   `eval(q5)`  or `eval(e5)`  in our running example

Comment: @NickS : To get 10, you evaluate the call/expression, i.e., call `eval(.)` on it.  My point was that people should not use `parse(text=.)` but rather `quote(.)` etc, to construct the call  which later will be `eval()`ed.

Comment: `eval(quote())` does work in a few cases but will fail for some cases where `eval(parse())` would work well.

Comment: I don't understand this solution still. I have a dataframe where one of the columns is a fraction (ie, "73/873") that's been stored as a string. I need to turn this into a decimal so I can sort/graph the data. When I try to use the included solutions, I can't get reference the variables correctly. So df[[1,1]] becomes "73/873", but quote(df[[1,1]]) simply produces "df[1,1]"

Comment: Let me give you a use case. If I want to join 80 data frames, whose names I get from vcdExtra::datasets as strings, then what is a better way than this: ```
data <- vcdExtra::datasets("dbdataset")
data$Item %>% 
    lapply( function(i) i %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval()) %>%
    Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y), .)```

Comment: `eval(quote("5+10*2"))` returns `"5+10*2"` whereas `eval(parse(text="5+10*2"))` returns `25`. In this case, `quote` doesn't seem to be the better function to use here...

Comment: @Dylan_Gomes, @NelsonGon:  I did *not* say, that `quote()` works when you give it a string.  You should *not* have strings at all, when you need expressions or calls.    Yes, sometimes your input does consist of strings, and you must parse these one way or the other, to *turn* them into expressions or calls which *then* you can evaluate.    Using packages such as `rlang` or `lazy_eval` do the same thing: Always two steps:  1. parse (which does "string" -> expression)  2. eval (expression -> "value").

Comment: @MartinMächler thanks for the clarification. It seems that this doesn't exactly answer the OP then. I understand that you are saying not to use strings at all, but one doesn't always have a choice. If you are handed a dataset that has character strings of equations, how does one evaluate them? There must be an acceptable way to do this, no?

Comment: @Dylan_Gomes:  Yes, as I say above, if you really get string data, you are "out of luck"  (because parsing is necessarily somewhat error prone), and you need 1. parse, 2. eval,  which indeed you can combine in one  `eval(parse(text= * ))`  (or any other variants of that).

Answer (score 35):

Not sure why no one has mentioned two Base R functions specifically to do this:  `str2lang()` and `str2expression()`.  These are variants of `parse()`, but seem to return the expression more cleanly:

```
eval(str2lang("5+5"))

# > 10
  
eval(str2expression("5+5"))

# > 10
```

Also want to push back against the posters saying that anyone trying to do this is wrong.  I'm reading in R expressions stored as text in a file and trying to evaluate them. These functions are perfect for this use case.

Comment: It's not that it's *always* wrong, it's just that there are many, many cases where it's safer and better to do things in a different way.

Answer (score 21):

Nowadays you can also use `lazy_eval` function from `lazyeval` package.

```
> lazyeval::lazy_eval("5+5")
[1] 10
```

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively, you can use `evals` from my `pander` package to capture output and all warnings, errors and other messages along with the raw results:

```
> pander::evals("5+5")
[[1]]
$src
[1] "5 + 5"

$result
[1] 10

$output
[1] "[1] 10"

$type
[1] "numeric"

$msg
$msg$messages
NULL

$msg$warnings
NULL

$msg$errors
NULL


$stdout
NULL

attr(,"class")
[1] "evals"
```

Comment: Nice function; fills a hole left by `evaluate::evaluate` by actually returning the result object; that leaves your function suitable for use for calling via mclapply.  I hope that feature remains!

Comment: Thank you, @rpierce. This function was originally written in 2011 as part of our `rapport` package, and have been actively maintained since then as being heavily used in our [rapporter.net](http://rapporter.net) service besides a few other projects as well -- so I'm sure it will remain maintained for a while :) I'm glad you find it useful, thanks for your kind feedback.

Answer (score 11):

Similarly using `rlang`:

```
eval(parse_expr("5+5"))
```

Comment: Came here looking for an `rlang` answer but what if any is the advantage of this over base alternatives? Actually, close examination of the code used shows that it is in fact using `eval(parse(....))` which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Not only those negatives, but its name is also misleading. It is NOT evaluating an expression. Should be called parse_to_expr ot something else to indicate that the user will know that it intended for character arguments.

Comment: It's just a wrapper that handles seamlessly any type of input (character, list, connection)

Answer (score 2):

I agree there are concerns around eval and parse, but if the expression is in a string, there appears nothing much that can be done. This eval parse is also used in the glue package by the tidyverse experts, see https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/blob/d47d6c7701f738f8647b951df418cfd5e6a7bf76/R/transformer.R#L1-L12

Perhaps the accepted answer of `eval(parse(text="5+5"))` has security concerns if the text string is from an untrusted source, eg imagine `user_input = "list.files()"` or worse file.remove...

One potential work around is below.

The idea is to set the R environment in which the expression is to be evaluated. In R, most functions that 'comes with R' are actually in packages that gets autoloaded at R start up, eg 'list.files', 'library' and 'attach' functions come from the 'base' package. By setting the evaluation environment to empty environment, these functions are no longer available to the expression to be evaluated, preventing malicious code from executing. In the code below, by default I include only arithmetic related functions, otherwise user can provide the evaluation environment with explicitly allowed functions.

```
eval_text_expression <- function(text_expression, data_list, eval_envir = NULL) {
  # argument checks
  stopifnot(is.character(text_expression) && length(text_expression) == 1)
  stopifnot(is.list(data_list))
  stopifnot(length(data_list) == 0 || (!is.null(names(data_list)) && all(names(data_list) != "")))
  stopifnot(all(!(lapply(data_list, typeof) %in% c('closure', 'builtin'))))
  stopifnot(is.null(eval_envir) || is.environment(eval_envir))
  # default environment for convenience 
  if (is.null(eval_envir)) {
    arithmetic_funcs <- list("+" = `+`, "-" = `-`, "*" = `*`, "/" = `/`, "^" = `^`, "(" = `(`)
    eval_envir = rlang::new_environment(data = arithmetic_funcs, parent = rlang::empty_env())
  }
  # load data objects into evaluation environment, then evaluate expression
  eval_envir <- list2env(data_list, envir = eval_envir)
  eval(parse(text = text_expression, keep.source = FALSE), eval_envir)
}

eval_text_expression("(a+b)^c - d", list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4))
# [1] 23
eval_text_expression("list.files()", list())
# Error in list.files() : could not find function "list.files"
eval_text_expression("list.files()", list(), eval_envir = rlang::new_environment(list("list.files" = list.files)))
# succeeds in listing my files if i explicitly allow it
```

Comment: That looks great, but I have a little trouble understanding how it works. Could you please explain it a bit how the solution addresses the security concerns? That would make the answer more meaningful. Thanks.

Comment: edited with explanations