# Implicit variable reference in R

Tags: r

How can I evaluate `c[,2]` through a call to `z`?

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6)
c <- cbind(a,b)
z <- "c[,2]"
```

`eval(z)` is not working.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Parsing arbitrary strings is unlikely to be the right answer.

Comment: Related: [R eval expression](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1743698/2157640)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be below:

```
eval(parse(text=z))
```

Comment: `require(fortunes); fortune(106)`

Answer (score 3):

If you **really** need to dynamically assemble a function call and then evaluate it, `do.call` is typically much better (and more efficient). It's a bit hard to pass the missing parameter though, but TRUE also works in this case:

```
z <- c[TRUE,2]
```

is equivalent to:

```
z <- do.call('[', list(c, TRUE, 2))
```

But here's a hack to get the missing symbol, which can then be used:

```
m <- quote(f(,))[[2]] # The elusive missing symbol
z <- do.call('[', alist(c, m, 2))
```