# R implicit remove of object

Tags: r

`ls()` gives among others and the following object: `object2remove`

Next we have the following code:

```
variableIuse <- "object2remove"
```

The question is:

How do I remove implicitly `object2remove` through the `variableIuse`?

Comment: This is a very simple extension of your previous question: [Implicit variable reference in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433825/implicit-variable-reference-in-r)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `list` parameter of the `rm()` function:

```
> object2remove <- 1:10
> variableIuse <- 'object2remove'
> rm(list = variableIuse) # remove variable named by variableIuse
> variableIuse            # still exists
[1] "object2remove"
> object2remove           # no longer exists
Error: object 'object2remove' not found
```