# How to convert a string in a function into an object?

Tags: r

I would like to convert a string that I pass in a function into an object (or column name).

I know that this works:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 11:20)

test.function <- function(x)            
{
  z <- df[[x]]
  return(z)
}
test.function("A")
```

I don't want to use the [[.]] operator, because sometimes it is unpractical or even not applicable. I am interessted in a general method to convert a string into an "object". Therefore I tried the following:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 11:20)

test.function <- function(x)
{
  z <- get(paste("df$", x, sep = ""))
  return(z)
}
test.function("A")
```

or

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 11:20)

test.function <- function(x)
{
  z <- as.name(paste("df$", x, sep = ""))
  return(z)
}
test.function("A")
```

or

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 11:20)

test.function <- function(x)
{
  z <- df$as.name(x)
  return(z)
}
test.function("A")
```

I also tried to play around with the parse, do.call and eval functions. Unfortunatelly I failed

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The trick is to use `parse`. For instance:

```
> x <- "A"
> eval(parse(text=paste("df$", x, sep = "")))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

See also this Q/A: [Evaluate expression given as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/r-eval-expression)

Comment: If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
—Thomas Lumley R-help (February 2005) -- PS, i upvoted because I can't think of a better way either :)

Comment: @JDLong Yea regular indexing by column name with `[` is always sufficient for me. Then you can take one column, or 2, or whatever...

Answer (score 7):

I just got an upvote which brought me back after 5 years to this question. I still think that the correct answer is `[[` despite the OP's request not to use it, but here's a way to dress up `[[` as a more functional "function".

```
df <-     structure(list(x = 1:3, y = 1:3), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

 test.function <- `[[`    # So simple, `test.function` now has all the features desired.
 df
 x y
 1 1
 2 2
 3 3
 test.function(df, "x")
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Or if it were desireable to hard code pulling an object named 'df' from the calling environment, a proposition that seems of dubious safety:

```
 test.df_txt <- function(var, dfn ='df' ){ get(dfn)[[var]] }
 test.df_txt("x")
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Original response (still not recommended):

You can sidestep around the limitations of "$" if you are willing to use eval(parse(text=...)) :

```
 test.function <- function(x)  {
   z <- eval(parse( text=paste("df$", x, sep = "")), env=.GlobalEnv)
   return(z)
   }
test.function("A")
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

BUT ... it is much better to use "[[". (My initial efforts at `eval(parse()`-ing were stuck at not knowing enough to use the "text" argument to `parse`.)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `eval(parse(text=YOUR_STRING))`, you can use `as.symbol` as a potential alternative.

Comment: Yes, `eval(as.symbol(YOUR_STRING))` worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable name from a string using the assign operator, as in:
assign("a_string", NULL)

Answer (score 1):

The function call nicely does what you want like this:

```
x <- data.frame(a = c(TRUE, FALSE, NA), b = 1:9, c = dnorm(-4:4), d = exp(-4:4 * 1i), `syntaxically invalid name` = LETTERS[1:9], check.names = FALSE)


solution <- function (string)
eval(call(name = "$", quote(x), as.symbol(string)))


print(solution("a"))
print(solution("syntaxically invalid name"))
```

If you wanted to be able to specify the name of the object you're retrieving the column from, try:

```
x <- data.frame(a = c(TRUE, FALSE, NA), b = 1:9, c = dnorm(-4:4), d = exp(-4:4 * 1i), `syntaxically invalid name` = LETTERS[1:9], check.names = FALSE)
y <- x
y$b <- y$b * 2L


solution <- function (object.name, string)
eval(call(name = "$", as.symbol(object.name), as.symbol(string)))


print(solution("x", "b"))
print(solution("y", "b"))
```