# Use information of an JSONstring in functions in R

Tags: r, json, character, transformation

I have a list converted from a JSON-string which looks like this:

```
print(p)
$species
[1] "Ratte"
$value
[1] "fitness"
$aggregation
[1] "mean"
```

I would like to use the information given the list as arguments in a function to transform a data-frame [Data] like this:

```
transformedData <- dcast(
Data[Data$species==p[[1]],],run_nr~paste(p[[2]],"_value",sep = ""),fun.aggregate = p[[3]]
)
```

This part

```
Data[Data$species==p[[1]],]
```

does work, of course.
unfortunately I do not know how to deal with the character strings of the other ones. I tried to convert the variables with `as.name(paste(p[[2]],"_value",sep = ""))`  and `as.function(p[[3]])`, without success... does anyone knows a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
For the string addressing the column in the data.frame use `eval` and `parse`, like in this post:

[How to convert a string in a function into an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196109/how-to-convert-a-string-in-a-function-into-an-object)

for the function use `str2lang("mean")`

works like a charm!!!