# Multi line text inputs in shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, line-breaks

What are my options to realize text inputs with multiple lines/line breaks (either explicit or just soft-wraps for nicer output in the UI) in shiny?

I'd like to implement an app that has a description/details field and the content being entered will most likely be more than just one line.

Basically, I'm looking for something to realize a similar functionality of the very text input box of stackoverflow I'm writing this question in: line breaks, scroll bar and/or (auto-)adjustment of height.

### Example

```
# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  p(),
  textInput("title", "Title"),
  textInput("description", "Description"),
  tags$hr(),
  h3("Database state"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("datatable")
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$datatable <- DT::renderDataTable(
    data.frame(
      Title = input$title,
      Description = input$description,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you want something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452465/how-to-create-textarea-as-input-in-a-shiny-webapp-in-r ?

Comment: @Vongo: that looks promising, thanks for the pointer! "Mutliline input" does in fact describe better what I'm after than "line breaks"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using `textAreaInput` instead of `textInput`.
With the former you can set height and width, and it automatically will wrap to next line if line is too long.

[Here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/textAreaInput.html) is where it is mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Note that `textAreaInput` requires shiny v0.14 or later