# How to add bigger textInput box in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am creating a Shiny App, where in one part I need the user to input a text summary, but the default size of text input box appearing in the App is very small. difficult for users to enter a summary of 3-4 lines. Could you help me with the script that can make the text input box bigger. really appreciate your help!

[image: Snapshot from my App]

===========
I just tried the following with HTML tags:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$textarea(id="my_textarea", rows=5, "Leave a comment...")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("my_output")
    )
  )
))
```

---

but got some error - shown below!

Comment: I am trying the following but each time getting the following error in my Shiny App. "ERROR: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"


shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$textarea(id="my_textarea", rows=5, "Leave a comment...")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("my_output")
    )
  )
))

Comment: It works for me as-is. The only `$` shown is `tags$textarea`, which should exist if you've loaded shiny (and haven't defined another variable called `tags`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a small aesthetic change(css to 100%), but it does work as it is. The error might be from some other section of your code. See the example below.

```
library(shiny)

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
           tags$style(type="text/css", "textarea {width:100%}") ,
           tags$textarea(id="my_textarea", rows=5,placeholder =  "Leave a comment...", "") 
    ) 
    ,mainPanel( h4('My panel') )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {}) 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ron Talbot ... it worked after adding "shiny::tags"

Comment: `shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
      shiny::tags$style(type="text/css", "textarea {width:100%}") ,
      shiny::tags$textarea(id="my_textarea", rows=5,placeholder =  "Leave a comment...", value="") 
    ) 
    ,mainPanel( h4('My panel') )
  )
))`

Comment: had to remove "value" argument for the text to be displayed,...good answer anyway!

Answer (score 7):

Try using `textAreaInput` instead of `textInput`. With the former you can set height and width, and it automatically will wrap to next line if line is too long.

This seems to be a duplicate of this question; [Multi line text inputs in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34330509/multi-line-text-inputs-in-shiny/41295201#41295201)