# How could I output several plot and values in R function?

Tags: r, function, math, statistics, return

There are several questions:

1 In an R function, "return" only can output one plot or value. But now, I want the function output every plot or vector I require, how could I achieve that. Which code should I use.

2 I have a series of variables : Game1~Game10 and I built up a do loop to analysis each of them where I represented their name as
**"paste("Game",i, sep="")",**
But it is characters, and I cannot do it like a variable like
**"sort(eval(paste("Game",i, sep="")))"**
is fail. How could I make R recognize the characters series as a variable name.

Comment: For your second question: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/r-eval-expression (you need to use `parse`)

Comment: @Jealie Thank u so much! But I need some further help. I tried it like : eval(parse(paste("Game",i,sep="")))  There is Game1 in my workfile and it said :"cannot open file 'Game1': No such file or directory
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to return more than one value from a function, use a data structure, that can store more values and return it, e.g. a vector, list or a dataframe

```
...
vector_1 <- 1:10
vector_2 <- 11:20
return( list(vec_1=vector_1, vec_2=vector_2) )
```

to output more than one plot, simply use a loop within the function e.g.

```
for(i in 5:10) plot(1:i)
```

Your second question is not clear to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Like a1<-c(1,2) and How could I represent the number of variable a1 into something like "a"&i.  In my loops, I want to represent variable regularly. But R just reads them as characters or strings instead of variable. How could I tell R clearly which is string and which is variable.

Comment: I have added some comment on my question, perhaps these will help u to understand my meaning.

Comment: I think you should try a simpler approach. Instead of pasting togehter numbers and variable names why don't you use a list? E.g.:
`a <- list()` and then `for(i in 1:10) a[[i]] <- c(1,2)`
This gives you the list "a" with a vector element for every loop run...

Comment: Yeah! It is a good way to solve it. Thank you so much! I does offer me a great help!

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped, you can accept my answer or vote it up as beeing useful. Thanks