# R : Column operation on a data frame

Tags: r

I have a column in my data frame `df` called `Ratio` which comprises of two positive integers `x` and `y` separated by a `/` [That is, format the is `x/y`]. I would like to replace each row in this column by `integer((x/y)*10)` (rounded off to the nearest integer)

Example, if that value of an element in `Ratio` is `14/20` I need to change it to `7`.

[There is a level `0/0` in the `Ratio` column in which case I would like it changed to `5`]

Comment: What is the `class(df$Ratio)`? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: You have not specified what you tried and where you got stuck

Comment: possible duplicate of [R eval expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/r-eval-expression)

Comment: `class(df$Ratio)` is `factor`

Comment: I tried `df$Ratio = as.integer(df$Ratio)` . Ended up with weird values.

Comment: @moonshinebutter, probably your values were 1 for the first level, 2 for the second and so on...

Comment: @Henrik yeah you are right. Never popped up in my search though.

Comment: @CathG thanks for the clarification and also the spoon-feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
# an example data frame
> dat <- data.frame(Ratio = c("0/0", "14/20"))

transform(dat, Ratio2 = sapply(strsplit(as.character(Ratio), "/"), function(x) 
  if (x[2] == "0") 5 else round(Reduce("/", as.integer(x)) * 10)))
#   Ratio Ratio2
# 1   0/0      5
# 2 14/20      7
```

Comment: Hey this one is good too. Actually I like this one better because it separates the numbers individually which I suddenly happen to need.

Answer (score 0):

```
df$Ratio<-as.character(df$Ratio)
df$resRatio[df$Ratio!="0/0"]<-sapply(df$Ratio[df$Ratio!="0/0"],
                                     function(expr) {
                                           round(eval(parse(text=expr))*10,0)})
df$resRatio[df$Ratio=="0/0"]<-5
```

Comment: And that was perfect. So `as.character` makes it possible to change levels. Ah.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use `as.integer`?

```
> as.integer(14.001/20.01*10)
[1] 7
```

Comment: What `as.integer` has to do with anything here? What just `14/20*10` gives you? I also toubt he has `14/20` in his `Ratio` column, otherwise R would transfer it to `0.7`