# Refer in name of element to other element

Tags: r

I have a problem in R and it is the following: 
How can you assign a value to an element and then later recall an element in who's name you refer to the previously defined element.

Thus you define an element x

```
i <- value
```

Later you use x.i where "i" should be its value.

This is a problem in the following two cases:

1)
First you create 10 elements with the name x.1 till x.10

```
for(i in 1:10){
        assign(paste0("X.", i), 1:3)
}
```

Then you want to change the name of the elements in x.1 till x.10

```
for(i in 1:10){
        assign(names(paste0("X.", i)), c("foo","bar","norf"))
}
```

This does not work.

2)
I want to define two values:

```
year <- 1
code <- 2
```

And then in a dataframe "Data.year" (="Data.1") only those observations where the colum "code" is equal to the value of the previously defined "code" (=2) should be stored. With the name format: "Data.year.code" (=Data.1.2)

```
assign(paste0("Data.", i, code, sep="."), as.name(paste("Data",year , sep="."))[as.name(paste("Data",y , sep="."))$code==code,])
```

Here I tried to use as.name function in but this does not work.
The problem is that R can obviously not reconise that "year" and "code" in the expression "Data.year.code" have a value. In stata you solve this by using `, But I do not now how you do this in R.
Normally I just google something when I do not know the answer. But I have no idea how I should name this problem and thus can't find it...

It should have an easy and straightforward solution.

Comment: So essentially what you need is to be able to call a variable by string?

Comment: Don't assign to the global environment like that. Collect these objects in a `list` or a different `environment`. That will make the whole task (at least what I understood of it) easier, tidier and possibly safer.

Comment: @LyzandeR: I don't think that that is what I want to do. Or maybe I do not fully understand what you mean. In the case of `names(paste0("X.", i))' R reads a string "X.(value of i)" while I want it to recognize "X.(value of i)" as an element with a value. So that I use Paste is not correct but I do not know how to do it in a different way.

Comment: So essentially you need exactly what I 'm saying :P. `paste0('X',i)` will return a string and therefore `names()` won't be able to recognise it (because it is a string and not a variable which you would like).

Comment: @Roland: Is using lists the only option. Because in the end I would like to define a large number of data frames and I would prefer not to store them in lists.

Comment: I like Akrun's way below but if it seems overly complicated to use `names<-()` which is actually the `names()` assignment function, you can also have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/r-eval-expression

Comment: Thank you all for your responds! @LyzandeR: I assume you refer to using `parse(text="string")` but how does this help me in my case?

Comment: There's no logical reason to create a large number of data frames and not store them in a list. A list of data frames is simply a [large] number of data frames with a little organisation applied. Its a good thing.

Comment: Probably you guys are right that I should store them in a list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea (although I need to tell you that it is a bit frowned upon by the R community) is to make a 'big' string in the loop which will be evaluated afterwards:

This works as you say:

```
 for(i in 1:10){
  assign(paste0("X.", i), 1:3)
}
```

and so in order to change the names you do the following:

```
for(i in 1:10){
   eval(parse(text=sprintf('X.%s <- c("foo","bar","norf")',i)))
}
```

Output:

```
> X.1
[1] "foo"  "bar"  "norf"
> X.2
[1] "foo"  "bar"  "norf"
```

So you make the big string with `sprintf` in this occasion:

```
> cat(sprintf('X.%s <- c("foo","bar","norf")',i)) #cat is used for demonstration here
X.1 <- c("foo","bar","norf") #this is the string for i==1 for example
```

and then you convert it to an expression with `parse` and then you evaluate the expression with `eval`.

As I said previously it is not the best technique to use but to be honest it has helped me quite a few times.

Comment: @Akrun sorry . Which first assign do you mean?

Comment: This is indeed the kind of solution I was looking for! This works in all cases.

Comment: @LyzandeR I may have missed some key points.  Anyway, I was referring to the one in my Update.

Comment: @akrun Yeah I was the first one in the comments to say that I like your way and that it works great. I also support the opinion that making a list is the best solution. I just wanted to show an alternative of how it can work with a string and `eval(parse...))`

Comment: @LyzandeR Thanks for that.  I was trying to understand the difference in techniques.  Not in a bad way :-)

Comment: @akrun I know akrun thanks. I never thought you downvoted. I upvoted yours as you know. You always mean well I know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code with `assign`, an option is (but as @Roland mentioned in the comments, it would be easier and safer to work with a "list")

```
for(i in 1:10){
 assign(paste0('X.',i), `names<-`(get(paste0('X.', i)), 
        c('foo', 'bar', 'norf')))
 }

X.1
#foo  bar norf 
#  1    2    3 
X.2
# foo  bar norf 
#  1    2    3
```

Or you can try it in a list

```
 lst <- lapply(mget(paste0('X.',1:10)), function(x) {
                names(x) <- c('foo', 'bar', 'norf')
              x})
```

If you need to change the original variables to reflect the changes

```
 list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

#### Update

If you need to change the values in the vector, it is easier

```
 list2env(lapply(mget(paste0('X.', 1:10)), 
   function(x) x <- c('foo', 'bar', 'norf')), envir=.GlobalEnv)

 X.1
#[1] "foo"  "bar"  "norf"
```

Or just

```
 for(i in 1:10){
   assign(paste0('X.', i), c('foo', 'bar', 'norf'))
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your responds! However I thought this solved it but now I tried to apply this solution to the second problem I mentioned in my question and there it does not work. The first problem I created to give a simpler example of what is in fact the same problem. Or is using `\`names<-\`` a general way of solving this and do I just not understand it?

Comment: @Jan-Pieter Do you want to change the elements in each of the vectors as Lyzander showed.  I thought you want the names to be changed as in the question.

Comment: In my question I tried to give two examples of the same problem. The names changing problem was just the first example. In the second case I wanted to change the vector multiple times in the same line. Sorry if I was not clear, maybe by giving multiple examples I made it just confusing. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @akrun He wanted the names Akrun in the first example you are right. I think it is the methodology that worked for Jan in the end in his actual problem.

Comment: @LyzandeR Thanks, I was curious. Jan-Pieter, Sorry didn't read the second part thoroughly