# How to evaluate a variable as an expression for axis label in R?

Tags: r, eval

**Objective is to allow user to pass a string to a plotting function and have it evaluated correctly as [`plotmath`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html).**

Question is how to combine an evaluated expression with other string text.

*It seems the presence of any other string or expression nullifies the evaluation of the label.*

Example:

```
label1 <- 'degree~C'

plot(1:10, type='l', xlab=bquote(.(parse(text=label1))))  #evaluated correctly
plot(1:10, type='l', xlab=bquote('Some text'~~Omega^2~~.(parse(text=label1))))  #missing degree C
```

Here is the output of the second plot showing that `label1` is missing:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Other (*possibly misguided*) attempts:

```
plot(1:10, type='l', xlab=substitute(paste('Some text'~~Omega^2~~mystring), list(mystring=label1))) #string not evaluated
plot(1:10, type='l', xlab=substitute(paste('Some text'~~Omega^2~~mystring), list(mystring=parse(text=label1)))) #string missing entirely
plot(1:10, type='l', xlab=substitute(paste('Some text'~~Omega^2~~mystring), list(mystring=expression(text=label1)))) #string missing entirely
```

Similar: [Evaluate expression given as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string)

Comment: `eval(parse(text=label1))`. Parse just creates an expression. Use `class` on the objects to find out... That's what the answer in the question you linked also clearly states.

Comment: Egads, you are indeed right.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `eval(parse(text=label1))`, like the linked answer suggests, or more simply, `paste("First part", label1)`.