# I have multiple time series and need to put them in one data.frame

Tags: r

I have around thirty separate time series in R. I would like to put them all inside one large data set but can not seem to do this.

I have used the following code but it doesn't work. All my time series are names ts1,ts2 etc. if i was to do df <- data.frame(ts1,ts2) this works individually but not if I input it this way

```
for(i in 2:nrow(deal)) 
{ 
temp <- paste("ts",i,sep="")
mystring <- paste(mystring,temp,sep=",") 
} 
df <- data.frame(mystring)
```

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38715951/edit) to update your post, with further info and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `df <- data.frame(ts1,ts2)` works, the following should work:

```
N <- nrow(deal)   # or whatever number of time series you have
df <- data.frame(sapply(1:N, function(i) eval(parse(text=paste("ts",i,sep="")))))
```

Notes:

1. `sapply` loops over sequence from `1` to `N` and applies a function. The results of the function are gathered as columns to a matrix that is then coerced into a data frame.
2. The function that is applied constructs the string for the name of the `i`-th time series and uses [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string) to evaluate the expression from the string. This returns the time series.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you