# Code autocompletion with lists in RStudio

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio

Given the following list, do I need to choose between cleaner code or autocompletion or can I have both? I'm using the newest version of RStudio on MacOS 10.10.5.

```
> l <- list()
> l$`__a` <- data.frame(`__ID` = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 1), col = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 1), check.names = F )
> l$`__b` <- data.frame(`__ID` = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 1), col = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 1), check.names = F )
> l$`__c` <- data.frame(`__ID` = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 1), col = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 1), check.names = F )
```

Autocomplete, but with backtick symbols (less clean and more difficult to programmatically manipulate):

```
> l$`__a`
   __ID col
1     i   u
2     4   V
3     b   Y
4     j   B
5     k   d
6     Z   Q
7     T   H
8     f   A
9     j   Y
10    k   P
```

With the `[` operator and strings (more clean and easier to programmatically manipulate, but without autocomplete):

```
> l[["__a"]]
   __ID col
1     i   u
2     4   V
3     b   Y
4     j   B
5     k   d
6     Z   Q
7     T   H
8     f   A
9     j   Y
10    k   P
```

Or is there a third possibility, for example writing all of the code first with backtick symbols and then finding a way to automatically replace them with `[[` and `]]`?

Comment: auto-complete also works with `[[` extraction. Enter: `l` (the object name), then `[[` and hit the tab button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, it's possible to have both autocomplete and nicely formatted code. In RStudio, autocomplete works for both `$` and `[[` but it functions slightly differently.

For indexing with `$`, the autocomplete list is triggered immediately after typing `$`.

However, for `[[`, it's necessary to press `tab` before the autocomplete list is shown. And this works multiple levels deep just as it does with `$`.

The comment above from `@docendo discimus` was helpful in finding this answer.