# R - filter data with dplyr using a test condition

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, eval

I'm trying to use `dplyr` to `filter` my data based on a test condition, but this test condition can change depending on other variables.

Using the built in sample dataset `cars`:

```
data(cars)
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
if (foo == 0) {
  test <- speed > 15
} else {
  test <- dist < 50
}
filter(cars, test)
```

This doesn't work. I can get it to work if I alter it to something like this:

```
if (foo == 0) {
  test <- 'cars$speed > 15'
} else {
  test <- 'cars$dist < 50'
}
filter(cars, eval(parse(text = test)))
```

But

1. Having to type out `cars$speed` and `cars$dist` seems to defeat the purpose of using the `filter` function.
2. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164111/1994092) SO answer, using the `eval(parse(text = ...))` construction is not recommended.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
library(dplyr)

if (foo == 0) {
  test <- cars$speed > 15
} else {
  test <- cars$dist < 50
}

filter(cars, test)
```

I don't see a problem on using `cars$speed` and `cars$dist` just because you are using `filter`. Also, do you really need to use `filter`? There's an alternative to do this using base R. Replace the last line by:

```
cars[test,]
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree that `cars[test,]` would be a better solution for this case - this was a simplistic example for the sake of a minimal code snippet for the question though. For some reason, this wasn't working for me when I tried to embed this in a function that takes in a df, column, and value and returned a filtered result set. But it actually seems to be working now using this sort of logic.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
filter(cars, if(foo==0){speed>15}else{dist<50})
```

Test by comparing with the simple filter:

```
> foo =0
> identical(filter(cars, speed>15), filter(cars, if(foo==0){speed>15}else{dist<50}))
[1] TRUE
> foo =1
> identical(filter(cars, dist<50), filter(cars, if(foo==0){speed>15}else{dist<50}))
[1] TRUE
```

It might just be easier and neater to put the `filter` statement inside the curly brackets:

```
if (foo == 0) {
  filter(cars, speed > 15)
} else {
  filter(cars, dist < 50)
}
```

Note if you want to assign the result somewhere, the `if` returns the value:

```
> ff = if (foo == 0) {
       filter(cars, speed > 15)
     } else {
       filter(cars, dist < 50)
     }
> identical(ff, filter(cars, speed>15))
[1] FALSE
> identical(ff, filter(cars, dist<50))
[1] TRUE
> foo
[1] 1
```