# Subset df on string condition

Tags: r, string, eval, subset

I want to subset `df` on an unknown condition (say, randomly defined as in the example below):

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b = 10:1)
condition <- paste0(sample(letters[1:2],1), sample(c("<",">"),1), sample(1:10,1))
```

I can do this with `eval`, which, vox populi, is suboptimal:

```
subset(df, eval(parse(text=condition)))
```

Is there an alternative to `eval(parse)`?

Comment: What do you mean by:`unknown condition`?

Comment: By `unknown condition`I guess it's a way to say : "I wrote a condition in a variable `condition` and then apply this condition on a dataset" ?

Comment: "unknown" as is programmatically defined: impossible to know beforehand. That's what the `sample` was intended to signify.

Comment: A tiny simplification would be `subset(df, eval(parse(text=condition)))` (though `subset` should only be used in interactive mode)

Comment: worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164111/4137985

Comment: Thanks, @Cath. I did read it: that's why I am looking for alternatives to `parse`.  Do you suggest an answer using `substitute()` or `quote()`?

Comment: well tbh right now I don't know how but there must be a way ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a slight adaptation to your script if becomes more feasible:

```
condition  <- list(value1 = sample(letters[1:2], 1),
                   comp =   sample(c(`<`, `>`), 1)[[1]],
                   value2 = sample(1:10, 1))

subset(df, condition$comp(df[, condition$value1], condition$value2))
```

So it depends on the constraints on how your condition is passed.

(Note that using `subset` might be a bad idea)

Comment: So, how is the `a*a*a-sin(2*pi*b)<0` condition is covered? Are we talking about linear combination?

Comment: I am assuming OP used that method to make a reproducible example, in reality they might be getting the condition directly as string. Maybe OP can clarify.

Comment: @Axeman, that's really useful. Indeed, I provided the condition as a string just as an example.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work since `condition$comp(condition$value1, condition$value2)` returns a single boolean value. `subset(df, condition$comp(df[,condition$value1], condition$value2))` might be an alternative.

Comment: @Axeman, I'll be happy to accept the answer if you change this to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If there can be some constraints introduced, such as the dataframe only having numeric columns, and only linear conditions, you could formulate the decision on condition as dot products:

```
# a > b
condition.mat <- c(1, -1)
condition.const <- 0

# b > 4
# condition.mat <- c(0, 1)
# condition.const <- 4

dec <- as.matrix(df) %*% condition.mat - condition.const
sel <- dec > 0

print(df[sel,])
```

Comment: Thanks, Surak. This is great to know. Unfortunately my example was misleading, since the columns of my df are actually character.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the base `subset` is the `filter` function from `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b = 10:1)
condition <- paste0(sample(letters[1:2],1), sample(c("<",">"),1), sample(1:10,1))

library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(eval(parse(text=condition))
```

Comment: I was actually looking to bypass `eval(parse)` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Just one thought. There are other ways to keep the code dynamic without the (nasty) "character-expression", for example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b = 10:1)

mysubset <- function (f,x1,x2) {
  df[f(df[[x1]],x2),]
}

mycol <- sample(letters[1:2],1) 
myfun <- sample(c("<",">"),1)
mylimit <- sample(1:10,1)

mysubset(.Primitive(myfun),mycol,mylimit) # in my mind just as dynamic as eval-parse ..

mysubset(`<`,"a",4)
```