# Save a data frame with list-columns as csv file

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame that looks like this (3 columns as list).

```
A tibble: 14 x 4
                                                    clinic_name drop_in_hours appointment_hours   services
                                                          <chr>        <list>            <list>     <list>
     1                   Birth Control and Sexual Health Centre    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
     2 Black Creek Community Health Centre (Sheridan Mall Site)    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
     3 Black Creek Community Health Centre (Yorkgate mall Site)    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
     4                                         Crossways Clinic    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
     5                                       Hassle Free Clinic    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
     6                          Immigrant Women's Health Center    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
     7                          Rexdale Community Health Center    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
     8                            Rexdale Youth Resource Center    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
     9                         Scarborough Sexual Health Clinic    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
    10                                 Special Treatment Clinic    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
    11                            Taibu Community Health Center    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
    12                                                 The Gate    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
    13                                   The Jane Street Clinic    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
    14                                            The Talk Shop    <list [1]>        <list [1]> <list [1]>
```

I wanted to output it to as csv file. It has come to my attention that columns of data frames shouldn't be lists in R. So I did some google and found this [save data.frames with list-column](https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-is-best-method-to-save-and-read-data-frames-with-list-column/1718/2) so I tried it out :

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(drop_in_hours = map_chr(drop_in_hours, ~ capture.output(dput(.))),
         appointment_hours = map_chr(appointment_hours, ~ capture.output(dput(.))),
         services = map_chr(services, ~ capture.output(dput(.)))     ) %>% 
  write_csv("health.csv")
```

But I got an error , am I missing something here?

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Result 4 is not a length 1 atomic vector
```

.

Comment: I suppose you didn't transforn your `df` into a tibble, like illustrated in the link you mentioned.

Comment: No, it is a tibble

Comment: do you want the list items to be expanded in the CSV file?

Comment: @Cybernetic I have this list for one observation < list(c("Monday: 2 pm - 5 pm", "Tuesday: 4 pm - 7 pm")) and I want to save file as csv to have a single row for each observation(clinic_name) --- I want to have Monday: 2 pm - 5 pm", "Tuesday: 4 pm - 7 pm (in a single row) in my csv file

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Create a tibble containing list columns:**

```
library(tibble)

clinic_name <- c('bobo center', 'yoyo plaza', 'lolo market')
drop_in_hours <- list(c("Monday: 2 pm - 5 pm", "Tuesday: 4 pm - 7 pm")) 
appointment_hours <- list(c("Monday: 1 pm - 2 pm", "Tuesday: 2 pm - 3 pm")) 
services <- list(c("skin graft", "chicken heart replacement"))

tibb <- data_frame(clinic_name, drop_in_hours, appointment_hours, services)

print(tibb)
```

[image]

**Write a general-purpose function that converts any list columns to character type:**

```
set_lists_to_chars <- function(x) {
    if(class(x) == 'list') {
    y <- paste(unlist(x[1]), sep='', collapse=', ')
    } else {
    y <- x 
    }
    return(y)
}
```

**Apply function to tibble with list columns:**

```
new_frame <- data.frame(lapply(tibb, set_lists_to_chars), stringsAsFactors = F)

new_frame
```

[image]

**Write newly formatted dataframe as csv file:**

```
write.csv(new_frame, file='Desktop/clinics.csv')
```

[image]

This is a csv file with the list columns expanded as regular strings.

**Here is an all-encompassing function. Just pass in your tibble and a filename:**

```
tibble_with_lists_to_csv <- function(tibble_object, file_path_name) {
    set_lists_to_chars <- function(x) { 
        if(class(x) == 'list') { y <- paste(unlist(x[1]), sep='', collapse=', ') } else { y <- x  } 
        return(y) }
    new_frame <- data.frame(lapply(tibble_object, set_lists_to_chars), stringsAsFactors = F)
    write.csv(new_frame, file=file_path_name)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
tibble_with_lists_to_csv(tibb, '~/Desktop/tibb.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks, this was great! I think that the "all-encompassing function" has `tibb` where `tibble_object` is required.

Comment: Thanks. tibb is a tibble object.

Comment: yes, but you are calling `tibb` inside the function where it hasn't been defined.

Comment: Gotcha...fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: This function doesn't seem to be rowwise, If the answers where different for bobo center and yoyo plaza, it would use the first line results in the entire tibble. Is it the same for you ? Any idea how to make it rowwise ?

Comment: As pointed by @HugoLehoux, the function does not evaluate by row. Here's a slight modification that works row-wise:

`set_lists_to_chars <- function(x) {
  if(class(x) == 'list') {
    y <- sapply(seq(x), function (y) paste(unlist(x[y]), sep='', collapse=', '))
  } else {
    y <- x 
  }
  return(y)
}`

Answer (score 15):

Here's another option that may be a little simpler.

Depending on the data, comma separated values could get complicated, so I'm using a bar `|` for separating values in list columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

starwars %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.list, ~paste(unlist(.), collapse = '|')) %>% 
  write.csv('df_starwars.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

`starwars` is one of the `dplyr` sample dataframes.

Comment: and you can reverse with `mutate_if(~any(str_detect(., fixed('|'))), ~str_split(., fixed('|')))`

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar dataframe with list columns that I wanted to save as csv. I figured out this method. As well as how to turn the columns back into lists.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create a df with a list column
df <- tibble(x=rep(1:5,each=2), y=LETTERS[1:10]) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(z=list(y))

# this throws an error
write_csv(df, "test.csv")

# convert the list column to a string
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(x) %>% # where x==unique(x)
  mutate(z=paste(z))

# this works
write_csv(df2, "test.csv")

# read the csv
df3 <- read_csv("test.csv")

# reconstruct original df by parsing the strings
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string
df4 <- df3 %>%
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(z=list(eval(parse(text=z))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason why you would like to save the columns as a list ? Alternatively, you can use `unnest` and save it in csv. example below

```
library(tidyverse)
df_list<-data_frame(abc = letters[1:3], lst = list(1:3, 1:3, 1:3))
df_list %>% unnest() %>% write.csv("list.csv")
```

further, when you read the file you can `nest` it back

```
df <- read.csv("list.csv")[ ,2:3]
df %>% nest(lst)
```

Comment: I created list-columns for each variable that has multiple entries (for example, four entries for services, three entries for appointment_hours,etc). I wanted to collapse all the services for a each clinic into a list, in order to have a single row for each clinic, and a variable that is a list of all services it offers, instead of a row for every service, for every clinic.

Comment: as of 2021 I get error: 'cols' is now required when using unnest

Answer (score 1):

`exploratory::list_to_text()` will convert a `list` column to a `character` column. The default is `sep = ", "`, which I recommend changing to something else if writing to a .csv.

`devtools::install_github("exploratory-io/exploratory_func")`

```
list_to_text <- function(column, sep = ", "){
  loadNamespace("stringr")
  ret <- sapply(column, function(x) {
    ret <- stringr::str_c(x, collapse = sep)
    if(identical(ret, character(0))){
      # if it's character(0)
      NA
    } else {
      ret
    }
  })
  as.character(ret)
}
```

https://github.com/exploratory-io/exploratory_func/blob/master/LICENSE.md

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the example from [@cybernetic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036488/8280804), the following solution using dplyr::mutate_if works for me.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

clinic_name <- c('bobo center', 'yoyo plaza', 'lolo market')
drop_in_hours <- list(c("Monday: 2 pm - 5 pm", "Tuesday: 4 pm - 7 pm")) 
appointment_hours <- list(c("Monday: 1 pm - 2 pm", "Tuesday: 2 pm - 3 pm")) 
services <- list(c("skin graft", "chicken heart replacement"))

tibb <- data_frame(clinic_name, drop_in_hours, appointment_hours, services)

# unlist if column is list
tibb_unlisted <- tibb %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.list, 
    funs(paste(unlist(.), sep='', collapse=', ')))
# print on screen, can see values
print(tibb_unlisted)
```