# R Shiny - Programmatically generate checkboxes in shinymaterial

Tags: r, shiny, material-design, metaprogramming

I'm working with a package in R called `shinymaterial`, which allows me to build R Shiny apps with material design elements. One element that I need to use is a group of checkboxes based on data uploaded by the user. However, the `shinymaterial` package has not yet implemented checkbox *groups*, only singular checkboxes. Unfortunately, it has masked the use of stock R shiny checkbox groups in the process, so I cannot simply fall back on those.

My best guess at a solution is to write a function that can programmatically generate a series of singular checkboxes based on an input vector of labels. **What should I use in order to do that?** Or is there **a totally different approach that might work instead?**

My attempt at a solution is to write a function that builds a string containing the commands for several singular checkboxes (mainly using `paste0` and a `for` loop). I planned on simply converting that string to an expression and then `eval`ing it. However, when I did that (example code below), the Shiny web page just renders the text of the command rather than executing it as a UI element.

```
materialCheckboxGroupGen <- function(idBase, choices, initials, color) {
  #' Generate a group input made from several material_checkbox elements
  #'
  #' Generate shinymaterial checkboxGroupInput expression Use `eval` to run the expression in your app.
  #' @param idBase String. Serves as a base for the inputId of the checkboxes; each checkbox's inputId will start with idBase and have a number appended.
  #' @param choices A character vector containing the labels for each checkbox to be made, respectively.
  #' @param initials A logical vector indicating the initial value for each checkbox to be made, respectively. Defaults to all FALSE, unchecked.
  #' @param color A character vector containing the color for each checkbox to be made, respectively. \emph{This input requires using color hex codes, rather than the word form. E.g., "#ef5350", rather than "red lighten-1".}

  #Setup
  nBoxes <- length(choices)
  if (missing(initials)) initials <- rep(FALSE, length.out = nBoxes)
  command <- NULL

  #Color will be recycled if it is not long enough
  if (length(color) != nBoxes) {
    color <- rep(x = color, length.out = nBoxes)
    warning("Length of color input not the same as number of choices. Color vector recycled to match.")
  }

  #Loop to generate commands
  for (i in 1:nBoxes) {
    #Set up all the arguments
    id <- paste0("\"", idBase, as.character(i), "\"")
    lab <- paste0("\"", choices[i], "\"")
    init <- as.character(initials[i])
    col <- paste0("\"", color[i], "\"")

    #Add a comma before all but the first checkbox
    if (i != 1) command <- paste0(command, ", ")

    #Add a new checkbox command to the end of the string
    command <- paste0(command,
                      "material_checkbox(input_id = ", id,
                      ", label = ", lab,
                      ", initial_value = ", init,
                      ", color = ", col,
                      ")")
  }

  return(command)
}

#Example
materialCheckboxGroupGen(idBase = "testing", choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3"), color = "#ef5350")
# [1] "material_checkbox(input_id = \"testing1\", label = \"Choice 1\", initial_value = FALSE, color = \"#ef5350\"), material_checkbox(input_id = \"testing2\", label = \"Choice 2\", initial_value = FALSE, color = \"#ef5350\"), material_checkbox(input_id = \"testing3\", label = \"Choice 3\", initial_value = FALSE, color = \"#ef5350\")"

#Bugs
#Merely wrapping the output of this function in eval(expression()) just renders the text of the output in the Shiny page, rather than executing it to create checkbox elements
```

Here's a small working example of that function in use, showing that it renders out the text of the command rather than the checkboxes instead:

```
require(shiny)
require(shinymaterial)

ui <- material_page(
  title = "Material Checkbox Groups",
  material_row(
    material_column(
      width = 12,
      material_card(
        title = "Example",
        eval(expression(materialCheckboxGroupGen(idBase = "testing", choices = c("Choice A", "Choice B", "Choice C"), color = "#EF5350")))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: The page generated by the MWE]

I suspect there may be an alternate way to do this, perhaps involving `quote` and `substitute` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164111/8037567) to related question, but I'm not totally familiar with those commands.

Comment: I would suggest amending the title of the question to "Programmatically generate  checkboxes in shinymaterial" as this seems closer to the intent of your question. See my updated answer for a non-`eval` based approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `eval(parse(...))` construct works fine.  Let the output of `materialCheckboxGroupGen` be a vector (like the `out` object below), then use `eval(parse(...))`.  Here's a minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

out <- c('material_checkbox(input_id = \"testing1\",
                            label = \"Foo\",
                            initial_value = FALSE,
                            color = \"#ef5350\")',
         'material_checkbox(input_id = \"testing2\",
                           label = \"Bar\",
                           initial_value = FALSE,
                           color = \"#ef5350\")')

ui <- material_page(
  title = "shinymaterial",
  tags$br(),
  material_row(
    material_column(
      width = 2,
      material_card(
        title = "",
        depth = 4,
        lapply(out, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
      )
    ),
    material_column(
      width = 9,
      material_card(
        title = "Output here",
        depth = 4
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  NULL
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This gives you

[image]

---

**Addendum.** Note that in your application, there is no need to use the `eval(parse(...))` construct.  Here is an alternative implementation.

`make_checkboxgroup` is a function that takes a character vector (e.g. `c("foo", "bar"`) and returns a list of `material_checkbox` values.

```
make_checkboxgroup <- function(x) {
  lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
    material_checkbox(input_id = paste0("var", i), label = x[i])
  })
}
```

In the `ui` object, we dynamically generate the checkboxes given, in this example, a comma-separated string of labels provided by the user. The main panel dynamically displays the status of each textbox.

```
ui <- material_page(
  title = "shinymaterial",
  tags$br(),
  material_row(
    material_column(
      width = 3,
      material_text_box("string", "Variables"),
      uiOutput("checkboxes")
    ),
    material_column(
      width = 9,
      material_card(
        title = "Output here",
        depth = 4,
        htmlOutput("checkbox_status")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

In the `server`, we use `do.call(material_card, ...)` to generate the checkboxes. We use `renderUI` to generate the output in the main panel.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$checkboxes <- renderUI({
    X <- strsplit(input$string, ",")[[1]]
    do.call(material_card, c(make_checkboxgroup(X), title = "", depth = 4))
  })
  output$checkbox_status <- renderUI({
    X <- strsplit(input$string, ",")[[1]]
    status <- sapply(paste0("var", seq_along(X)), function(i) input[[i]])
    HTML(paste(X, status, collapse = '<br/>'))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked great! To make it a bit cleaner to call, I also put the lapply(output, function(x) eval(parse(text = x))) as the object returned by my materialCheckboxGroupGen function.

Comment: (RE: Addendum) I wish I could upvote your answer a second time. That's a much more elegant solution to the root problem I was facing. Thank you!

Comment: I did it for you @twieg ;)