# How to convert a string to a formula with the type of `language` in R?

Tags: r

I want to convert a string with a formula to an object with the type `language` in order to use it as a formula.

How can I accomplish this?

A short example, that shows the problem:

```
formula <- "(1 - sin(x^3)"
> typeof(formula)
[1] "character"
```

A working reference is

```
> typeof(quote(1 - sin(x^3)))
[1] "language"
```

Of course, I can't just write formula in quote:

```
> quote(formula)
formula
```

So, is there a way to convert a string in a vector to something that as the typeof `language`?

Comment: This question touches on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `parse`:

```
y <- "1 - sin(x^3)"
p <- parse(text = y)[[1]]

p
## 1 - sin(x^3)

is.language(p)
## [1] TRUE

typeof(p)
## [1] "language"

x <- pi/4
eval(p)
## [1] 0.5342579
```

Note that `is.language(parse(text = y))` is also TRUE but it is of type `expression`.  On the other hand, `eval(parse(text = y))` gives the same result.