# Pass argument from user provided function to aggregate (stats)

Tags: r

I am looking to create a function that aggregates sale data by many different variables. I am running into a snag with aggregate(by =). Here is my function thus far:

```
func <- function(x, x2, statfunc) {

  PT <- c(1,5,3,5,4,8,3,1,5,6,1,5,5,6,1,2,3,1,5,1)
  SH <- c(7,7,3,1,1,1,1,4,4,6,6,7,7,1,1,1,3,2,1,3)
  SaleRatio <- c(0.85, 0.92, 0.89, 0.88, 0.86, 1.08, 1.15, 1.03, 0.95, 1.01, 1.36, 0.96, 1.03, 0.95, 0.90, 1.01, 0.96, 0.95, 0.81, 1.29)

  study <- data.frame(PT, SH, SaleRatio)

  study <- select(study, x2, SaleRatio)

  study <- aggregate(study,
              by = list(x),
              FUN = statfunc)
print(study) 
}
```

When I attempt to run my formula with:

```
func(x = "study$PT", x2 = "PT", statfunc = median)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(study, by = list(x), FUN = statfunc) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

I am expecting this:

```
  Group.1 PT SaleRatio
1       1  1     0.990
2       2  2     1.010
3       3  3     0.960
4       4  4     0.860
5       5  5     0.935
6       6  6     0.980
7       8  8     1.080
```

The results above are from the **exact** same formula, only by manually entering the arguments instead of letting the function pass them.

This user provided function will eventually be applied with many different variables and aggregate functions, and on a much larger data set.

Can someone assist?

Comment: There are some issues in the function as well as in arguments, `"study$PT"` is not evaluated as intended

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Thanks for providing a well formatted question that shows effort on your part. Your issue is that the arguments you're passing to the function are strings, not the objects themselves. So they are evaluated as a character vector of length 1.

Comment: Another thing that would help is not to define the data inside the function. You should define it outside, then pass the data to the function as argument(s).

Comment: You can use `eval` and `parse`. Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string

Comment: Thank you all, the solution provided by @akrun worked perfectly with my larger data set, and with user provided functions as the "statfunc".  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
func <- function(x, x2, statfunc) {

  PT <- c(1,5,3,5,4,8,3,1,5,6,1,5,5,6,1,2,3,1,5,1)
  SH <- c(7,7,3,1,1,1,1,4,4,6,6,7,7,1,1,1,3,2,1,3)
  SaleRatio <- c(0.85, 0.92, 0.89, 0.88, 0.86, 1.08, 1.15, 1.03, 0.95,
        1.01, 1.36, 0.96, 1.03, 0.95, 0.90, 1.01, 0.96, 0.95, 0.81, 1.29)

  study <- data.frame(PT, SH, SaleRatio)

 study %>% 
      select(x2, SaleRatio) %>%
      group_by_at(x) %>%
      summarise_all(statfunc)

}


func("PT", "PT", median)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#     PT SaleRatio
#  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1     0.99 
#2     2     1.01 
#3     3     0.96 
#4     4     0.86 
#5     5     0.935
#6     6     0.98 
#7     8     1.08
```