# Parse a string to use as an argument

Tags: r

I am trying to parse a string to use as an argument. It throws the following error.

```
Error in parse: <text>:1:10: unexpected ','
```

This is the part of my code:

```
type <- input$info_type
arguments <- paste(type, collapse=", ")
tmp <- rbind(eval(parse(text=arguments)))
```

`input$info_type` is an input from Selectize, and
I expect the code to work like this:
if: `argument <- "data_1, data_2"`
then, execute: `rbind(data_1, data_2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate expression given as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Library(stringr)

arguments = str_c(string = input$info_type, collapse=", ")

or

arguments = input %>% paste(type, collapse=", ")

Comment: When I assign `arguments` as the ones you suggested and do `rbind(arguments)`, it just returns the `arguments` string itself, like `selection1,selection2,selection3`