# Evaluate an expression given as a string inside substitute()

Tags: r, substitution

I would like to evaluate an expression given as a string inside `substitute()`, but I don't get the expected output (an x-axis label "My index"... with the subscript):

```
mystrng <- "index[1]" # string
plot(0~1, xlab = substitute("My"~ind, list(ind = mystrng))) 
plot(0~1, xlab = substitute("My"~ind, list(ind = parse(text = mystrng))))
plot(0~1, xlab = eval(substitute("My"~ind, list(ind = parse(text = mystrng)))))
```

Note:

1) Without `substitute()`, one can work with `parse(text = mystrng)`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string/40164111). As this link also reveals, one should not work with strings, but, e.g., `quote(index[1])` which works with the first `plot()` call above. I'm just interested in how one would go about strings.

2) The last `plot()` call trial was inspired by `?substitute`

3) Ideally the solution would also work if `mystrng` contains blanks, like `"My index[1]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse()` returns an `expression`, which is essentially a list of language objects marked as a different type.  You want to put a language object into the title, so I think this is what you want:

```
plot(0~1, xlab = substitute("My"~ind, list(ind = parse(text = mystrng)[[1]])))
```

That gives this as the x label:

[image]

This won't work if `mystrng` isn't legal R syntax, so `"My index[1]"` will need some preprocessing to convert it to something legal like `"My~index[1]"`