# What is an alternative to this eval parse code?

Tags: r, eval

I am inserting some code into someone else's custom R package and I don't have flexibility to write it how I would like.

I need to be able to sum up many variables following a similar format that I can re-create with formulas.

**I am looking for a more efficient way to write this.**  Efficiency is important because there is a lot of data to process.

Here is sample code showing what I want to do, but it is slow and clunky.  I know eval-parse is not the best way to do this, that's why I'm asking for a better way :-)

```
v1 <- 1
v2 <- 2
v3 <- 3
v4 <- 4

# this for loop works, but it is clunky and slow
string <- character()
for (i in 1:4) {
  if (i < 4) string <- c(string, paste0("v",i,"+"))
  else string <- c(string, paste0("v",i))
}
eval(parse(text=string))
```

Comment: Looks like `Reduce("+", mget(paste0("v", 1:4)))`

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string)?

Comment: 1) You don't need a loop to form the string: `paste0("v", 1:4, collapse = "+")`. 2) An alternative to @akrun's `Reduce` can be `Reduce("+", mget(ls(pattern = "^v\\d+$")))`.

Comment: akrun's answer is perfect, thank you!!

Comment: Thanks d.b, I will have to benchmark those methods vs the Reduce solution when I get the chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` after getting the object values in a `list`

```
Reduce(`+`, mget(paste0("v", 1:4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you talk about formulas, maybe `reformulate()` can help

```r
reformulate(paste0("v",1:4))
#> ~v1 + v2 + v3 + v4
```

You can get your expected output by using the following, though in that case it's less efficient and less intuitive than @akrun's approach :

```
eval(reformulate(paste0("v",1:4))[[2]])
#> [1] 10
```