# How to filter a dataframe with a character vector

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I'm trying to filter a data.frame with `filter()` function from the package `dplyr`. The main problem here is that I want to use a vector for the conditions.

For example

```
library(dplyr)
conditions <- c("Sepal.Width<3.2","Species==setosa")
DATA <- iris %>%
  filter(conditions) #This doesnt work, of course.
```

Is there any function that would take

```
conditions <- c("Sepal.Width<3.2","Species==setosa")
```

as an input and give me

```
Sepal.Width<3.2 & Species==setosa
```

as an output? I though about using `eval(parse...)` with `sapply`and maybe `paste0()` to add the `&`, but can't make it work.

Any help would be aprecciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues. First, you need to quote inside quotation for the second condition:

```
conditions <- c("Sepal.Width < 3.2", "Species == 'setosa'")
```

Then, you need to specify the association between the two conditions. Here, I assumed an `&`. Then you can use `eval(parse(...))`:

```
iris %>%
 filter(eval(parse(text = paste(conditions, sep = "&"))))

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
```

On the other hand, I think it is always important to quote [@Martin Mächler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string) to warn about the potential problems associated with this approach:

> The (possibly) only connection is via parse(text = ....) and all good
>   R programmers should know that this is rarely an efficient or safe
>   means to construct expressions (or calls). Rather learn more about
>   substitute(), quote(), and possibly the power of using
>   do.call(substitute, ......).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didnt notice the quotation in setosa, it worked for me! As I asked to @sindri_baldur, do you know any other way to do it without the Eval(parse)?

Answer (score 3):

Here is *a* way:

```
conditions <- c("Sepal.Width<3.2","Species=='setosa'")
# note the small change here:               ↑      ↑
DATA <- iris %>%
  filter(eval(parse(text = paste(conditions, collapse = "&"))))

> DATA
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
3           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
4           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
5           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa
6           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
7           5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2  setosa
8           4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2  setosa
9           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
10          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
11          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
12          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa
```

Comment: I see, I don't know why  It didnt work in first instance for me. Thanks, do you know if there's a way to do it without the eval(parse..)?

Comment: @kowa we might have an XY problem. What is your application?

Comment: I will use to to classify data, so I would be the only one with acces to the code, thats why I'm not affraid of XSS attack, but wouldnt mind to be safer.

Answer (score 2):

A tidyeval way would be to use `rlang::parse_exprs()`.

```
library(dplyr)

conditions <- c("Sepal.Width < 3.2", "Species == 'setosa'")

iris %>%
  filter( !!! rlang::parse_exprs(conditions))

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
3           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
4           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
5           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa
6           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
7           5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2  setosa
8           4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2  setosa
9           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
10          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
11          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
12          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa
```