# Plotting MA / SMA / RMA regressions lines (smatr or lmodel2 packages) into ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

I would be very grateful for advise on how to plot Standardised Major Axis (SMA) regressions lines into a faceted ggplot. I used the following code:

## Run the SMA analysis and create a data frame with the SMA reg line coefficients (intercept and slope) I want to plot

```
smaReg = sma(Y ~ X * Type, data = ExampleData)
summary(smaReg)
smaSummary <- data.frame(Type = 1:6,coef(smaReg))
```

## ggplot code using geom_abline to plot SMA regressions

```
ModFit <- ggplot(ExampleData, aes(y = Y, x = X, color = Level)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme_classic() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Type, nrow = 2, ncol = 3) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 12)) +
  annotate("segment", x = -Inf, xend = Inf, y = -Inf, yend = -Inf, color = 'black', size = 1) +
  annotate("segment", x = -Inf, xend = -Inf, y = -Inf, yend = Inf, color = 'black', size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 60, by = 20)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 120, by = 20)) +
  geom_abline(data = smaSummary, aes(intercept = elevation, slope = slope)) +
  labs(x = expression(paste("Predicted (",mu,"mol m"^{-2},"s"^{-1},")")), y = expression(paste("Observed (",mu,"mol m"^{-2},"s"^{-1},")"))) +

ModFit
```

This code has two remaining issues I need to resolve but my beginner coding skills are not good enough yet to tackle them successfully:

1. I used annotate() and scale_x_continuous to plot the same axes and scales across all faceted plots, however, this solution does not plot the X axis ticks and I haven't found a way to do this without something else going wrong when I make a change.
2. When I run this plot code, I get the error message below:

**Error in wrap_dims(n, params$nrow, params$ncol) : 
  nrow * ncol >= n is not TRUE**

In trying different ways of solving this error, I noticed that if I change the labs() layer to the very simplified version shown below:

```
labs(x = expression(X), y = expression(Y), color = "Level") +
```

This change produces a faceted plot but with all the SMA regressions on each plot. I have no idea why changing the labs() layer allows the plot to be produced! I have run out of ideas (and google searches) on how to plot only the corresponding SMA reg line for each plot while also adding the detailed axis labels I need without something else going wrong.

[Faceted plot with simplified labels and all SMA reg lines on each plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwhrT.png)

Many thanks in advance for any advise on how to solve these two remaining issues!

Comment: Can you include a some of the ExampleData? Including sample data using the `dput(head(x))` function will help others answer your question.

Comment: There are multiple questions here. I'd split out the axis titles issues from the faceting plots/axis -- the separate questions might help the community read and answer.

Comment: Hello Ravic, before posting my question I tried to upload a data file but I couldn't find a way to do it. Is there a way to do this that I missed?

Comment: Regarding separating the two questions, I thought I had done this by numbering them. This is only the third time I post a question, is there a particular way to post two related questions?

Comment: Here's a link describing how to structure a good reproducible question, including how to include sample data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Not a complete answer, but on the labels, you likely need `bquote()`, pretty well described here: https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/2246/

Comment: I've already tried using quote() but without success

Comment: @Dodo It is long since you asked the question, but I have now added a full answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is close, but not exactly an answer to the axis label part of the question. It is, however, a full answer to adding a major axis regression to a facetted ggplot. Trellis plots, from which facets derive, are meant to be a matrix of similar plots and thus share the axis labels. The only way of having different axis labels is to make the plots individually and to compose the final figure from them using, for example, package 'patchwork'. Anyway, in general, annotations derived from the data are usually included in the plotting area or highlighted along the axes. The examples below achieve the highlighting, labelling and adding the MA regression using statistics from package 'ggpmisc' and geometries from package 'ggpp', re-exported by 'ggpmisc'.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)
#> Loading required package: ggpp
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggpp'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     annotate

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ma_line() +
  stat_centroid(color = "red") +
  stat_centroid(geom = "rug", color = "red") +
  labs(title = "test", 
       x = expression("Observed "*(mu*mol~m^{-2} ~ s^{-1})), 
       y = expression("Predicted "*(mu*mol~m^{-2} ~ s^{-1}))) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ma_line() +
  stat_centroid(color = "red") +
  stat_centroid(color = "red", geom = "rug") +
  stat_centroid(aes(label = sprintf("bar(x)~`=`~%.1f*\";  \"*bar(y)~`=`~%.1f", 
                                    after_stat(x), after_stat(y))), 
                geom = "text_npc", 
                color = "red", npcy = 0.95, npcx = 0.05,
                hjust = "inward", vjust = "inward",
                parse = TRUE) +
  labs(title = "test", 
       x = expression("Observed "*(mu*mol~m^{-2} ~ s^{-1})), 
       y = expression("Predicted "*(mu*mol~m^{-2} ~ s^{-1}))) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ma_line() +
  stat_centroid(color = "red") +
  stat_centroid(color = "red", geom = "rug") +
  stat_centroid(aes(label = sprintf("bar(x)~`=`~%.1f*\";  \"*bar(y)~`=`~%.1f", 
                                    after_stat(x), after_stat(y))), 
                geom = "text_npc", 
                color = "red", npcx = 0.95, npcy = 0.05,
                hjust = "inward", vjust = "inward",
                parse = TRUE) +
  labs(title = "test", 
       x = expression("Observed "*(mu*mol~m^{-2} ~ s^{-1})), 
       y = expression("Predicted "*(mu*mol~m^{-2} ~ s^{-1}))) +
  facet_wrap(~Species, scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`stat_ma_line()` and its companion `stat_ma_eq()` are wrappers on `lmodel2` and support most of the underlying options. Please, have a look at the documentation for ['ggpmisc'][1] and for ['ggpp'][2] for the details. The examples above, for simplicity use the default `"lmodel2:MA"`, but `stat_ma_line()` also supports `SMA` and `RMA` as methods.

The geoms from 'ggpp' that use native plot coordinates (npc) allow the same code to be used with `"free"` and `"fixed"` panel axis scales.

Answer (score 0):

(UPDATED: Added greek math symbols)

Let's tackle the labels, which are pretty thorny in your example. I'm using the iris dataset here as a sample, but using your axis titles.

The key is using `bquote()` to get the math, the dynamic variables and everything else ready.

- A lot more detail available here: https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/2246/
- And on SO: [Evaluate expression given as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string)

```r
library(tidyverse)
mu_val <- 5.1
bq_x <- bquote("Predicted (" ~ mu ~ "=" ~ .(mu_val) ~ " mol " ~ m^-2 ~ s^-1 ~ ")")
bq_y <- bquote("Observed (" ~ mu ~ "=" ~ .(mu_val) ~ "mol m" ~ m^-2 ~ s^-1 ~ ")")

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "test", x = bq_x, y = bq_y)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

@ravic_ thanks to your advise I am now able to produce a faceted plot with the correct labels using the revised code below:

My updated my ggplot code:

```
bq_x <- bquote("Predicted (" ~mu~"mol" ~ m^-2 ~ s^-1 ~ ")")
bq_y <- bquote("Observed (" ~mu~"mol" ~ m^-2 ~ s^-1 ~ ")")

# 1a. Plots by PFTs
ModFit <- ggplot(ExampleData, aes(y = Y, x = X, color = Level)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme_classic() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Type, nrow = 2, ncol = 3) +
  # customise facet labels
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 12)) +
  annotate("segment", x = -Inf, xend = Inf, y = -Inf, yend = -Inf, color = 'black', size = 1) +
  annotate("segment", x = -Inf, xend = -Inf, y = -Inf, yend = Inf, color = 'black', size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 60, by = 20)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 120, by = 20)) +
  labs(x = bq_x, y = bq_y) +
  geom_abline(data = smaSummary, aes(intercept = elevation, slope = slope))
```

The two remaining problems now are:
1. Add Y and X axis lines with ticks across all faceted plots
2. Add the corresponding single SMA reg line to each plot

Many thanks again for all your help @ravic_!

Comment: Thanks so much ravic, but why is mu (the symbol/greek letter for micro) declared as 5.1? I have looked at different ways of using Greek letters with bquote(), e.g. *mu~, but have not found a way that works yet.

Comment: @Dodo, sorry, thought you were trying to include a dynamic value. I updated the entry with both the Greek character, and a dynamic value. Turns out that with `bquote()`, you don't need to do the tricks that we're used to in writing Latex in other places.

Comment: many thanks for both the coding solution and the links! The "thinkerrstuff,,," link was particularly useful as it explains the syntax very clearly. I've updated my code to: