# Correct display of chemical formulae in ggplot axis category labels

Tags: r, parsing, ggplot2, subscript, chemistry

I'm plotting a data set with chemical formulae as categories, and values associated with each:

```
data <- data.frame(compound = factor(c("SiO[2]", "Al[2]O[3]", "CaO")),
                value = rnorm(3, mean = 1, sd = 0.25))
```

I want to get the subscripts in the chemical formulae to display correctly in the axis labels. I've tried various solutions involving `bquote()`, `label_parsed()`, `scales::parse_format()` and `ggplot2:::parse_safe` (as per [this thread](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3228)), but all of those give me either no category labels at all or a mess. For example:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = compound, y = value)) +
geom_col() +
scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::parse_format())
```

Gives this error message:

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = NULL) : 1:6: unexpected symbol
1: Al[2]O
         ^
```

Can anyone help? I've done this successfully before with the x axis and x-axis labels (via `labs()` and then `bquote()` or similar), and there are various threads I can see for that problem, but the same solutions don't seem to work for category labels.

Comment: Just recently wrote a pretty long `bquote()` answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924729/plotting-sma-regressions-lines-smatr-package-into-ggplot). Maybe that will help? I think you'll want to isolate the `bquote()` stuff just to the `labs()` label call.

Comment: Oh, apologies, just noticed you tried `labs()` and `bquote()` already. If you can include sample data using the `dput()` function, that will help me and others answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @ravic_. That example you linked to is a little different as the non-standard characters are in the axis label itself, rather than the categories along the axis.

I think the dummy data in my question is enough to reproduce the problem, but let me know if I'm missing something!

Comment: Harder than it looks, but think I have an workable solution for you now.

Comment: "Harder than it looks" - you're not wrong there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: Finally got the right `parse()` routine, so that if the chemicals are formatted correctly already in the dataframe, then they can simply be parsed to show the proper labels. (Note that aluminum oxide needs the tilde (~) character).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rlang'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     %@%, as_function, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_dbl, flatten_int,
#>     flatten_lgl, flatten_raw, invoke, list_along, modify, prepend,
#>     splice
compounds = c("SiO[2]", "Al[2]~O[3]", "CaO[1]")
data <- tibble(compound = compounds,
               value = rnorm(3, mean = 1, sd = 0.25))
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = compound, y = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = rlang::parse_exprs)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

PREVIOUS UPDATE: Replacing the code with something slightly more extensible with a translation table to obtain the `bquote()` expressions. Same basic idea, but not just hard-wiring in the labels now, so should work with filters, facets, etc.

```r
library(tidyverse)
compounds = c("SiO[2]", "Al[2]O[3]", "CaO[1]")
translation = c("SiO[2]" = bquote(SiO[2]),
                "Al[2]O[3]" = bquote(Al[2] ~ O[3]),
                "CaO[1]" = bquote(CaO))
data <- tibble(compound = compounds,
               value = rnorm(3, mean = 1, sd = 0.25))
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = compound, y = value)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = translation)
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Does the trick. Would still be interested in something that does this more systematically (for when there are more than a few formulae involved than in my little reprex), if you/anyone has any bright ideas. But for now, problem solved. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Okay @TimM, this was bugging me, and even though it sort of worked before, now the last update actually does what you want -- which is to parse the expressions that you already have maintained in your dataframe. Phew. Not doing that again. :)

Comment: Thanks. That's brilliant!

Comment: Using "Al[2]~O[3]" adds space, so it is better to use "Al[2]*O[3]" instead.