# How to put a string into the keyby parameter in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I know that I can do this,

```
x<- data.table( mtcars )
x[ , .N , by = as.numeric( gear==4 & carb==4) ]
```

But I don't know how to do it with character strings.  If I was using a single variable name, I could use `get()` and that would work

```
x[ , .N , by = get( "as.numeric( gear==4 & carb==4)") ]
```

Comment: Putting expression in a string is a sign of bad design, it is fine to use it, but one should not put such code in production. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164111/2490497

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is `eval(parse`

```
library(data.table)
x[ , .N , by = .(grp = eval(parse(text = "as.numeric( gear==4 & carb==4)") ))]
#   grp  N
#1:   1  4
#2:   0 28
```