# Paste0, subset Error: 'subset' must be logical

Tags: r, subset, paste, logical-or

I would like to use paste0 to create a long string containing the conditions for the subset function.

I tried the following:

```
#rm(list=ls())
set.seed(1)
id<-1:20
ids<-sample(id, 3)
 
 d <- subset(id, noquote(paste0("id==",ids,collapse="|")))
```

I get the

```
Error in subset.default(id, noquote(paste0("id==", ids, collapse = "|"))) : 
  'subset' must be logical
```

I tried the same without noquote. Interestinly when I run

```
noquote(paste0("id==",ids,collapse="|"))
```

I get `[1] id==4|id==7|id==1`. When I then paste this by hand in the subset formula

```
d2<-subset(id,id==4|id==7|id==1)
```

Everything runs nice. But why does `subset(id, noquote(paste0("id==",ids,collapse="|")))` not work although it seems to be the same? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why not just `subset(id, id %in% ids)` or `id[id %in% ids]`?

Comment: Maybe `subset(id, eval(parse(text = paste0("id==", ids, collapse="|"))))` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1743698/680068

Comment: `noquote` just changes the print method for a string. It does not force evaluation of a string as an expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both versions work well.