# list inside string to list in R

Tags: r, string, list

I have a string:

```
"list(id = '1001', status = c('xyz', 'abc', 'def', 'jkl'))"
```

I want to convert it to:

```
list(id = '1001', status = c('xyz', 'abc', 'def', 'jkl'))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate [Evaluate expression given as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just do `eval(parse`

```
out <- eval(parse(text = "list(id = '1001', status = c('xyz', 'abc', 'def', 'jkl'))"))
```

-output

```
out
$id
[1] "1001"

$status
[1] "xyz" "abc" "def" "jkl"
```

With `dput`, can get the structure

```
dput(out)
list(id = "1001", status = c("xyz", "abc", "def", "jkl"))
```