# Multiplication of certain column values R

Tags: r, tidy

I have a column in a dataset that looks like this :

- Actual
- chr
- 5.25%
- -5.50*1000000000
- 0.24%
- -4.00*1000
- 4.5%

My goal is to access it and automatically convert the cells that have *1000 or *1000000000 and make the calculation, ex -5.5 * 1000000000 should be - 5 500 000 000 on the cell and -4 * 1000 should be -4000.

Does anyone have a hint how to do this?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using first a splitting operation on `*` and then a mapping operation based on `purrr`'s function `map_dbl` to perform the calculations:

```
library(purrr)                                   
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  # Step 1: split strings on `*`:
  mutate(x_new = strsplit(x,"\\*")) %>%
  # Step 2: convert to numeric and perform calculation:
  mutate(x_new = ifelse(str_detect(x_new, ","), 
                        map_dbl(x_new, function(x) as.numeric(x)[1] * as.numeric(x)[2]),
                        x_new))
                 x    x_new
1 -5.50*1000000000 -5.5e+09
2              35%      35%
3       -4.00*1000    -4000
```

(warning messages can be ignored)

Test data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("-5.50*1000000000", "35%", "-4.00*1000"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! Perfect solution, may the force be within

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: By running on a bigger df with some empty cells "" I get the error :

Comment: Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: Sorry to hear. I can't see a problem on my end: when I have `df <- data.frame(x = c("-5.50*1000000000", "", "35%", "-4.00*1000", ""))` as test data, the code works fine.

Comment: thank you very much Sir, I just wasn't putting it in data frame. You are very important thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If your string is guaranteed to be a valid expression that R can evaluate literally, you can use

```
eval(parse(text = '-5*1000'))
```

This parses the string into R code equivalent, and then executes it using eval. In this case, it leads to a numerical result of -5000.

Tread with care. [More background on using eval(parse) can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string)

Comment: That’s correct, since 35% is not a valid r expression. You can work around (this particular case) with a string replacement of ‘%’ with ‘*0.01’