# Convert character vector of geometry into sfc_LINESTRING

Tags: r, datatable, spatial, r-sf

I have a data table as follows, which I need to convert into an sf object:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
    ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
    Value = 11:15
)
```

The geometry information for each ID is a character vector with differing number of coordinates making up the linestring. ID "B" has 4 coordinates; ID "C" has 5.

```
geo <- c("c(-112.116492521272, -112.116492811159, -112.116492812107, -112.116491781569, -112.116482854256, -112.116482819195, -112.116476331207, -112.116476325101, -112.11647589954, 33.3777109072744, 33.377733456163, 33.377733512504, 33.377817189599, 33.3785425053239, 33.3785454379367, 33.3790725760563, 33.3790731291841, 33.3791076444333)", 
         "c(-112.282916223332, -112.282955145531, -112.282977080374, -112.282986066594, 33.499285198973, 33.4994146786288, 33.4995335119373, 33.4998030580162)", 
         "c(-112.281058674957, -112.281058522318, -112.281057917087, -112.281057356648, -112.281055594103, -112.281047371356, -112.281048086137, -112.28104821173, 33.4937123457776, 33.4937301348982, 33.4938008007847, 33.4938659107566, 33.4940708243904, 33.4950232493953, 33.4951159682343, 33.4951322463168)", 
         "c(-112.282978024041, -112.282977000088, -112.282975472281, -112.282975387447, -112.282974470679, -112.282974464144, -112.282974284899, -112.28297410899, -112.282974107453, 33.5011764123633, 33.5013710145493, 33.5016617311961, 33.501678000948, 33.5018530730796, 33.5018546369058, 33.5018887965849, 33.5019223852857, 33.5019226044706)", 
         "c(-112.282986066594, -112.282985540911, -112.282984156895, -112.282983004093, -112.282982201845, 33.4998030580162, 33.4998965204233, 33.5001425170464, 33.5003478058912, 33.5004906801949)"
)
```

Adding the geometry information to DT:

```
DT$geometry <- geo
```

Now, I need to convert DT into an sf object with geometry specified as *sfc_LINESTRING*. I tried using *st_cast* to first convert the character-based geometry variable into linestring, but it yielded an error.

```
DT_sf <- st_cast(DT$geometry, "LINESTRING")
```

```
Error in UseMethod("st_cast") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_cast' applied to an object of class "character"
```

This conversion needs to be done for nearly 20,000 rows. So, I am looking for a computationally efficient way to achieve the required result.

Comment: Your geometry format - a text formatted somewhat like a R vector, with no clear separation of X and Y coordinates - is somewhat unusual. Is this the raw data? Also, in what coordinate reference system should the numbers be interpreted? I assume decimal degrees, but it is not quite obvious....

Comment: Actually, this reprex table is from a shapefile that was at one point loaded as a data frame and imported to a database as a dataset with all variables (including sfc_LINESTRING-coded geometry variable) in character format. So, this is the raw data when I read it from the database. The crs is 4326.

Comment: The format is indeed unusual, but, assuming this is given, I suggest you first find a way to parse the `geo` data into something that `sf` can work with - e.g., convert it to a list of matrices, where each matrix corresponds to one of the character vectors, and describe the points of the linestring. From there it should be easier to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1743698/5977215) to "evaluate an expression given as a string"

(This *can* be dangerious if your string isn't sanitised (think of SQL injection))

So with your `geo` object you get

```r
lst <- lapply(geo, function(x) { eval(parse(text = x)) })

str( lst )
List of 5
# $ : num [1:18] -112 -112 -112 -112 -112 ...
# $ : num [1:8] -112.3 -112.3 -112.3 -112.3 33.5 ...
# $ : num [1:16] -112 -112 -112 -112 -112 ...
# $ : num [1:18] -112 -112 -112 -112 -112 ...
# $ : num [1:10] -112 -112 -112 -112 -112 ...
```

Since we're evaluating each vector in geo one at a time (inside the `lapply`), we can also make it an sfg object at the same time

```r
lst <- lapply(geo, function(x) {
  v <- eval(parse(text = x))
  m <- matrix(v, ncol = 2)
  sf::st_linestring(m)
})
```

Then all that's needed is to add the correct class attributes

```r
DT$geo <- lst

DT$geo <- sf::st_as_sfc( DT$geo )
DT <- sf::st_as_sf( DT )
sf::st_crs( DT ) <- 4326

DT
# Simple feature collection with 5 features and 2 fields
# Geometry type: LINESTRING
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -112.283 ymin: 33.37771 xmax: -112.1165 ymax: 33.50192
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# ID Value                            geo
# 1  A    11 LINESTRING (-112.1165 33.37...
# 2  B    12 LINESTRING (-112.2829 33.49...
# 3  C    13 LINESTRING (-112.2811 33.49...
# 4  D    14 LINESTRING (-112.283 33.501...
# 5  E    15 LINESTRING (-112.283 33.499...
```

Comment: wow, this is better. learned something. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `c()` notation and then split the coordinates into a list. Then you can create a data frame and use e.g the upper half rows and latitudes. This can be converted in a matrix which is a format `st_linestring` understands:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     transpose

geo <- c(
  "c(-112.116492521272, -112.116492811159, -112.116492812107, -112.116491781569, -112.116482854256, -112.116482819195, -112.116476331207, -112.116476325101, -112.11647589954, 33.3777109072744, 33.377733456163, 33.377733512504, 33.377817189599, 33.3785425053239, 33.3785454379367, 33.3790725760563, 33.3790731291841, 33.3791076444333)",
  "c(-112.282916223332, -112.282955145531, -112.282977080374, -112.282986066594, 33.499285198973, 33.4994146786288, 33.4995335119373, 33.4998030580162)",
  "c(-112.281058674957, -112.281058522318, -112.281057917087, -112.281057356648, -112.281055594103, -112.281047371356, -112.281048086137, -112.28104821173, 33.4937123457776, 33.4937301348982, 33.4938008007847, 33.4938659107566, 33.4940708243904, 33.4950232493953, 33.4951159682343, 33.4951322463168)",
  "c(-112.282978024041, -112.282977000088, -112.282975472281, -112.282975387447, -112.282974470679, -112.282974464144, -112.282974284899, -112.28297410899, -112.282974107453, 33.5011764123633, 33.5013710145493, 33.5016617311961, 33.501678000948, 33.5018530730796, 33.5018546369058, 33.5018887965849, 33.5019223852857, 33.5019226044706)",
  "c(-112.282986066594, -112.282985540911, -112.282984156895, -112.282983004093, -112.282982201845, 33.4998030580162, 33.4998965204233, 33.5001425170464, 33.5003478058912, 33.5004906801949)"
)

parsed_geo <-
  geo %>%
  map(~ {
    .x %>%
      str_remove_all("c[(]|[)]$") %>%
      str_split(",") %>%
      first() %>%
      map_chr(str_trim) %>%
      as_tibble() %>%
      mutate(lon_lat = row_number() <= n() / 2) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = lon_lat, values_fn = list) %>%
      unnest() %>%
      type_convert() %>%
      as.matrix() %>%
      st_linestring()
  })
#> Warning: `cols` is now required when using unnest().
#> Please use `cols = c(`TRUE`, `FALSE`)`
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   `TRUE` = col_double(),
#>   `FALSE` = col_double()
#> )
#> Warning: `cols` is now required when using unnest().
#> Please use `cols = c(`TRUE`, `FALSE`)`
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   `TRUE` = col_double(),
#>   `FALSE` = col_double()
#> )
#> Warning: `cols` is now required when using unnest().
#> Please use `cols = c(`TRUE`, `FALSE`)`
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   `TRUE` = col_double(),
#>   `FALSE` = col_double()
#> )
#> Warning: `cols` is now required when using unnest().
#> Please use `cols = c(`TRUE`, `FALSE`)`
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   `TRUE` = col_double(),
#>   `FALSE` = col_double()
#> )
#> Warning: `cols` is now required when using unnest().
#> Please use `cols = c(`TRUE`, `FALSE`)`
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   `TRUE` = col_double(),
#>   `FALSE` = col_double()
#> )

DT <- data.table(
  ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  Value = 11:15
)
DT$geometry <- parsed_geo
DT
#>    ID Value                           geometry
#> 1:  A    11 LINESTRING (-112.1165 33.37...,...
#> 2:  B    12 LINESTRING (-112.2829 33.49...,...
#> 3:  C    13 LINESTRING (-112.2811 33.49...,...
#> 4:  D    14 LINESTRING (-112.283 33.501...,...
#> 5:  E    15 LINESTRING (-112.283 33.499...,...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
library(sfheaders)

DT <- data.table(
      ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
      Value = 11:15)

geo <- c("c(-112.116492521272, -112.116492811159, -112.116492812107, -112.116491781569, -112.116482854256, -112.116482819195, -112.116476331207, -112.116476325101, -112.11647589954, 33.3777109072744, 33.377733456163, 33.377733512504, 33.377817189599, 33.3785425053239, 33.3785454379367, 33.3790725760563, 33.3790731291841, 33.3791076444333)", 
         "c(-112.282916223332, -112.282955145531, -112.282977080374, -112.282986066594, 33.499285198973, 33.4994146786288, 33.4995335119373, 33.4998030580162)", 
         "c(-112.281058674957, -112.281058522318, -112.281057917087, -112.281057356648, -112.281055594103, -112.281047371356, -112.281048086137, -112.28104821173, 33.4937123457776, 33.4937301348982, 33.4938008007847, 33.4938659107566, 33.4940708243904, 33.4950232493953, 33.4951159682343, 33.4951322463168)", 
         "c(-112.282978024041, -112.282977000088, -112.282975472281, -112.282975387447, -112.282974470679, -112.282974464144, -112.282974284899, -112.28297410899, -112.282974107453, 33.5011764123633, 33.5013710145493, 33.5016617311961, 33.501678000948, 33.5018530730796, 33.5018546369058, 33.5018887965849, 33.5019223852857, 33.5019226044706)", 
         "c(-112.282986066594, -112.282985540911, -112.282984156895, -112.282983004093, -112.282982201845, 33.4998030580162, 33.4998965204233, 33.5001425170464, 33.5003478058912, 33.5004906801949)")

geo <- geo %>%  
  sub('c\\(', '', x = .) %>% 
  sub('\\)', '', x = .) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) x %>% 
           str_split_fixed(",", str_count(string = ., ',')+1) %>% 
           matrix(ncol=2) %>% 
           data.frame)

geom <- list()
for (i in seq(length(geo))){
  geom <- c(geom, sfheaders::sf_linestring(matrix(as.numeric(as.matrix(geo[[i]])), 
                                                  ncol=2)))
}

sequ <- seq.default(from = 2, to = length(geom), by = 2)

DT$geometry <- geom %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .[sequ]) %>% 
  st_sfc()

   ID Value                           geometry
1:  A    11 LINESTRING (-112.1165 33.37...,...
2:  B    12 LINESTRING (-112.2829 33.49...,...
3:  C    13 LINESTRING (-112.2811 33.49...,...
4:  D    14 LINESTRING (-112.283 33.501...,...
5:  E    15 LINESTRING (-112.283 33.499...,...
```