# Evaluate MULTIPLE equations writern in a character/string vector in R

Tags: r, dplyr

As many of you [have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string), to evaluate an equation writing in a string or character, one can use `eval(parse(text = "your equation"))` as follows:

```
"1+1"
eval(parse(text = "1+1"))
2
```

This works very well when you have only one equation. But when you have a vector of equations written as strings/characters, it only evaluates the last equation:

```
eval(parse(text = c("1+1","2+2","3+3")))
6
```

How could one evaluate all these expressions and have the vector of results at the end?

```
c(2,4,6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not vectorized, i.e. it needs to be looped

```
unname(sapply(c("1+1","2+2","3+3"), function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
[1] 2 4 6
```

---

If we know the operator, an option is also to either split up or use `read.table` to read as two columns and then use `rowSums`

```
rowSums(read.table(text = c("1+1","2+2","3+3"), header = FALSE, sep = "+"))
[1] 2 4 6
```

Comment: `unname(` approach is immune to ++-, is there an approach to achieve the same with `rowSums(read.table`? i.e. there are two sep(s).

Comment: I think the constraint is `read.table` rather than rowSums, and I'm trying to estimate if you get to 1mil before r questions get to 510K. Putting thumb on scale...

Comment: I meant if the expression is `c("1*2", "1+ 3 *5^2")` etc, rowSums wouldn't work.

Comment: which still works for `unname(sapply(` case so rowSums(read.table is really a more restrictive edge case, that is good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Purrr is your friend.

```
library(purrr)

equations <- c("1+1","2+2","3+3")

map_dbl(.x = equations, .f = function(equation){
  
  eval(parse(text = equation))
})

[1] 2 4 6
```

Comment: You have used `purrr`. Why not using a `purrr-style` function to make your code shorter? I.e. `map_dbl(equations, ~ eval(parse(text = .x)))`

Comment: Yes, that's also correct but I generally prefer being explicit to make my code easier to read.