# Data frame: calculate values for new column with function (and function parameters from additional dataframe)

Tags: r, dataframe, function, mutate

I have multiple data.frames ***(1)*** that have the following structure:

```
'data.frame':   50742 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ t        : num  0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 ...
 $ timepoint: POSIXct, format: "2021-03-19 01:00:00" "2021-03-19 01:20:00" "2021-03-19 01:40:00" "2021-03-19 02:00:00" ...
 $ year     : chr  "2021" "2021" "2021" "2021" ...
 $ month    : chr  "03" "03" "03" "03" ...
```

I want to add a new column to every data.frame. The values in this new column need to be calculate according to this function:

```
test <- function(s,r,t,m,n,a) {
  p=(((((s-r))/((t-r)))^(((1)/(m)))-1)^(((1)/(n))))/(a)
}
```

t are existing values in the date frame (first column)

s,r,m,n,a are parameters that are saved in a separate data.frame ***(2)***, that looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Area : chr  "TB" "TB" "TB" "TB" ...
 $ Sites: chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ Plot : chr  "num" "num" "num" "alph" ...
 $ depth: int  10 20 30 10 20 30 10 20 30 10 ...
 $ p    : num  0.561 0.467 0.455 0.509 0.507 ...
 $ a    : num  0.0484 0.0428 0.0421 0.0463 0.046 ...
 $ n    : num  2.08 2.39 2.48 2.14 2.25 ...
 $ m    : num  0.519 0.581 0.597 0.532 0.555 ...
 $ r    : num  0.0141 0.0153 0.0151 0.0285 0.0165 ...
```

For every unique data.frame ***(1)*** I need to add the column, data of parameters are in the **rows** of my second data.frame ***(2)***

I have no idea how to solve my problem, especially because my parameters are in a second data.frame.
Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want 15 `p` values for every row of table 1, based on each of the parameter sets? I presume you want something like `library(tidyverse); df1 %>% crossing(df2) %>% mutate(p=(((((s-r))/((t-r)))^(((1)/(m)))-1)^(((1)/(n))))/(a))`

Comment: How are the 15 observations in `df2` supposed to be aligned with the 50,742 observations in `df1`? I see no columns in common, nor a clear way to find intervals for range-based joining. Is it that your list of frames has 15 such frames, and you want to use one row each from `df2` for each of the list-of-`df1`? When you're answering this question, can you please add more-usable data? The output from `dput` is far better (unambiguous, less-work), please add something like `dput(head(df1,10))` assuming that that is a reprensentative sample. Thanks!

Comment: **df1**: `> dput(head(C_moist,10))
structure(list(theta_0 = c(0.118, 0.118, 0.119, 0.119, 0.119, 
0.119, 0.119, 0.119, 0.119, 0.119), timepoint = structure(c(1616112000, 
1616113200, 1616114400, 1616115600, 1616116800, 1616118000, 1616119200, 
1616120400, 1616121600, 1616122800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), year = c("2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021"), month = c("03", "03", 
"03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: **df2:**

`> dput(head(hi,3))
structure(list(Area = c("TB", "TB", "TB"), Sites = c("C", "C", 
"C"), Plot = c("num", "num", "num"), depth = c(10L, 20L, 30L), 
    s = c(0.560538462, 0.467038462, 0.454653846), a = c(0.048400664, 
    0.04279389, 0.04209948), n = c(2.077212753, 2.389174686, 
    2.480263317), m = c(0.518585663, 0.581445423, 0.596817002
    ), r = c(0.014135459, 0.015321546, 0.015079289)), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: I have 15 **df1** (all same structure). Each row of **df2** contains the params data for one of the 15 data frames. That means: **df1.1** goes with row 1 of **df2**, **df1.2** goes with row 2 of **df2**, **df1.3** goes with row 3 of **df2**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` an `parse` functions as explained here: [Evaluate expression given as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string):

```
for (i in 1:3) {
print(eval(parse(text=paste0("mean(df",i,"[,2])"))))
}
```

This chunk of code just calculate mean of second column of 3 data.frames, just playing with `i` variable, you can do the job.