# Compare number to string with ranges and single numbers

Tags: r, string

I have the following tibble

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- tibble(A = c("1994:2020, 2021"), B = 1995)
```

I would like to check if the year in B is in the years given in column A. The years in column A are a string (the data is read from an Excel file).
The following clearly doesn't work (it gives "No", but I would like to have "Yes"):

```
test %>%
  mutate(InA = ifelse(B %in% A, "Yes", "No"))

> test
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  A                   B
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 1994:2020, 2021  1995
```

I assume that I have to separate the string in A. However, A can contain more than one range and/or more than one year (e.g. ( "1994:2012, 2014, 2016:2020, 2021") and using "separate" for different structures gets complicated. Perhaps there is more straightforward way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tidyverse equivalent of @SamR’s strategy

```r
library(tidyverse)

test <- tibble(A = c("1994:2020, 2021"), B = 1995)

test %>%
  mutate(InA = map2_lgl(A, B, ~ .y %in% eval(str2lang(
    paste0("c(", .x, ")")
  ))))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   A                   B InA  
#>   <chr>           <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1 1994:2020, 2021  1995 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: If you're determined to use `tidyverse` functions wouldn't you replace `paste0("c(", .x, ")")` with `glue::glue("c({.x})")`? And you could probably use `rlang::eval_tidy()` and `rlang::parse_expr()` as well. ;)

Comment: Thanks to all for the insights and solutions! I used the solution of Anil as it is short and uses tidyverse.

Answer (score 12):

## Idea

If you just need to know if *one point falls into an interval*, you only need to know the relations between the point and both edges of that interval.

Mathematically, given a point `p` and an interval `[lb, ub]`, `p` is within the interval (incl. the edges) **if and only if** `(p-lb)*(p-ub) <= 0`, and thus you can try `prod(p - c(lb,ub))` and check its sign only.

## Code

You can try the code below (also, thanks for the data provided by [@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78126990/12158757))

```
transform(
    test,
    inrange = mapply(
        \(x, y) prod(y - range(as.numeric(x))),
        strsplit(A, "\\D+"), B
    ) <= 0
)
```

which gives

```
                A    B inrange
1 1994:2020, 2021 1995    TRUE
2 1994:2020, 2021 2021    TRUE
3 1994:2020, 2021 2022   FALSE
```

Comment: Thomas you are clearly much smarter than me :). I am kind of amazed by this approach. Why not just `findInterval(y, range(as.numeric(x)), right=TRUE)==1`, rather than this wizardry? Or even just `y >= min(x) && y <= max(x)`?

Comment: @SamR yes, `findInterval` is more readable and also an excellent option, I just forgot to use it. Thanks for the reminder :P. I myself usually prefer to keep the code as short as possible, and that's is the reason I didn't use `y >= min(x) && y <= max(x)`, but anyway it works well the same.

Answer (score 10):

Let's create a few more examples:

```r
test <- data.frame(
    A = c("1994:2020, 2021", "1996", "1994:2012, 2014, 2016:2020, 2021", "1994:2012, 2014, 2016:2020, 2021"),
    B = c(1995, 2022, 2015, 2019),
    expected = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
)
#                                  A    B expected
# 1                  1994:2020, 2021 1995     TRUE
# 2                             1996 2022    FALSE
# 3 1994:2012, 2014, 2016:2020, 2021 2015    FALSE
# 4 1994:2012, 2014, 2016:2020, 2021 2019     TRUE
```

If you trust your input you can evaluate it.

#### Base R solution

This is how I would do it.

```r
within(test, C  <- Map(
    \(x,y) y %in% eval(str2lang(x)), 
    sprintf("c(%s)", A),
    B,
    USE.NAMES = FALSE
))
#                                  A    B expected     C
# 1                  1994:2020, 2021 1995     TRUE  TRUE
# 2                             1996 2022    FALSE FALSE
# 3 1994:2012, 2014, 2016:2020, 2021 2015    FALSE FALSE
# 4 1994:2012, 2014, 2016:2020, 2021 2019     TRUE  TRUE
```

#### `tidyverse` solution

As you load `library(tidverse)` in your question you could also do:

```r
test |> 
    dplyr::mutate(
        C = purrr::map2_lgl(
        A,
        B, 
        \(x,y) y %in% rlang::eval_tidy(
            rlang::parse_expr(
                glue::glue("c({x})")
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Note that both these approaches will also work if `A` contains non-contiguous ranges, e.g. `1994:2012, 2014`, which not all answers will.

#### Mandatory disclaimer

With either approach, it is worth reading [Evaluate expression given as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string) and [What specifically are the dangers of eval(parse(...))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse). Do not use this approach if you do not control the input data. Imagine an input data frame containing strings like this.

```r
test <- data.frame(A = "warning('You have been hacked!')", B = 1995)
```

Both of these approaches will execute the code and print the warning. So if this is a possibility use a different approach.

Answer (score 9):

This won't be fast for large data but it works:

```
test <- data.frame(A = c("1994:2020, 2021", "1994:2020, 2021", "1994:2020, 2021"), 
                   B = c(1995, 2021, 2022))

test$ranges <- strsplit(test$A, ", ", fixed = TRUE)

foo <- function(x, y) {
  y <- strsplit(y, ":", fixed = TRUE)
  any(
    sapply(y, \(z, x) {
      z <- as.integer(z) 
      if (length(z) == 1L) return(z == x)
      x >= z[1] && x <= z[2] 
  }, x = x)
  )
}

mapply(foo, x = test$B, y = test$ranges)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

We first split the characters in individual ranges and then split these ranges to get their limits. Comparing with limits is easy as is comparing with a single year (instead of a range).

Answer (score 4):

This is another option how to do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
test <- tibble(A = c("1994:2020, 2021", "2000:2005, 2008:2010, 2015", "1980, 1985:1990", "1999:2002"), 
               B = c(1995, 2004, 1986, 3000))

test |> 
  mutate(
    InA = map2_lgl(B, str_split(A, ", "), ~ {
      years <- unlist(str_split(.y, ":|-"))
      any(.x >= as.integer(years[1]) & .x <= as.integer(years[length(years)]))
    })
  ) |> 
  mutate(InA = ifelse(InA, "Yes", "No"))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  A                              B InA  
  <chr>                      <dbl> <chr>
1 1994:2020, 2021             1995 Yes  
2 2000:2005, 2008:2010, 2015  2004 Yes  
3 1980, 1985:1990             1986 Yes  
4 1999:2002                   3000 No
```

Comment: This fails if `B` falls between ranges — for example, if `B` is changed to `2006` in row 2 and `1981` in row 3, it still returns `"Yes"` but should return `"No"`.